# why does the code > if 3 == 1 or 2: print('A') else: print('B') < print A but not B

Tags: python-3.x

I recently started learning my first programming language and i couldn't understand why this code gave me A as the answer and not B

```py
if 3 == 1 or 2:
    print('A')
else:
    print('B')
```

Comment: `3 == 1` is False, but `2` evaluates to True, so `False or True` is `True`.

Comment: because the right operation in `or` is `True`

Comment: I think you tried to compare like this: `if 3 == 1 OR 3 == 2: print('A') else: print('B')` In that case, you'd get `A`

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check for the two conditions `3==2` and `2`. `2` evaluates to `true`, so you get `A` as output.

If you want to check 3 for beeing 1 or 2, you have to do it like this:

```
if 3 == 1 or 3 == 2: print('A') else: print('B')
```

See e.g. [Do not understand why if condition evaluates to True when variable is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853301/do-not-understand-why-if-condition-evaluates-to-true-when-variable-is-integer) for details why 2 is true, especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853361/8725275) answer.

Answer (score 0):

In python it could be read as `if 3==1 or bool(2) == True` where the first condition if False and the second is True because `bool(2)` is True

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong assumption that `3 == 1 or 2` means "is 3 equal to 1 or 2?", but in reality it's rather "is either 3 equal to 1, or does 2 evaluate to True" and since 2 is non-zero value it *always* evaluates to `True`.

More specifically, `3 == 1 or 2` expression evaluates to `False or 2` then `False or True` and finally `True`.

If you want the expression that matches your original expectation, you should write `3 in [1, 2]` which checks whether 3 is in one of the allowed values in the list.