# Python, have a condition in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Someone came with this example to me (python2):

```
num = int(input("num")) 
den = int(input("den"))

quot = 0
rest = den
i = num

for i in range(i,i>den, -den):
  quot = quot + 1
  rest = i - den

print quot
print rest
```

The code runs fine, does what it needs to be doing, and doesn't produce errors.

I don't understand why. To me, `range()` requires a lower and an upper limit, and to me, `i` would be the lower value, while `i>den` should evaluate to a boolean?

The context is a tutorial function which implements division with a for loop.

Comment: can you add a bit more of the surrounding code? as written we don't know all the preconditions (like the initial values of `i` and `num`).

Comment: You can have a condition in a for loop but not a range function.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi No, you can, because `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0`. But it certainly wouldn't behave like a C-like's `for` statement. It's just setting the stop point of iteration to either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Yes, I meant for the intended purpose.

Comment: Looks to me that whoever wrote this code got Python for-loop syntax mixed up with the for-loop syntax in C, Java, JS, etc. Even if it is technically correct, it is absolutely not pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an application of "[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)".  In this case, `i>num` evaluates to a boolean value of `True` or `False`, but in the context of the `range` function, `True` is equivalent to the integer `1`, and `False` is equivalent to the integer `0`.

So, for example, if `i>num` is `False`, then that code is equivalent to

```
for i in range(i, 0, -num):
  #do stuff
```

Comment: Having said that, there is almost certainly a more clear way to write out the conditions for the iteration than using a clever trick like this, which in Python 2.X is technically relying on an implementation detail.

Comment: For sure - it's a weird bit of code, and not one I'd care to debug or maintain.

Comment: Gah, seeing the OP's update it's even crazier, since `i = num` entering the loop so it will *always* be `False`. WTF?

Comment: The update opened my eyes: as i gets initialized to num, then the condition i > num evaluates to True. The range(i, True) evaluates to for example (16, 1), which is an empty range []. BUT, as we have the step change -dev, if dev is 2 for example, the range results in [16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2] and that's why the code does what it needs to do!

Comment: @aruisdante What implementation detail?

Comment: @Veedrac in Python 2.X, boolean values are not *guaranteed* to be `0,1` when converted to int. This is simply their default. In Python 3.X, the language was changed to guarantee this conversion. See the question that @thedayturns linked to in his answer.

Comment: @faboolous `i > num` is always `False` for `i == num` ;) My guess is that the intention was to effectively remove an iteration for `i > num` if the preconditions were different. It's a "clever" trick, but in python clever is usually considered bad when it hampers clarity and readability.

Comment: @aruisdante Would you then say `int(1.0)` is an implementation detail because someone can reassign `int`?

Comment: @Veedrac No. The problem isn't that `bool()` can be reassigned, it's that `True` and `False` can, and their definition isn't codified in pre-3.X python. In fact `True` need not even be 1 to be compatible with languages like C, it need only be not-zero. Hence why in 2.X it's an implementation detail, where as in 3.X it's guaranteed by the language to be so as `True` and `False` are promoted to keywords rather than special constants.

Comment: @aruisdante What's the difference between reassigning `True` and reassigning `int`? Also, the builtin values for `True` and `False` *are* defined as `1` and `0`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Python considers `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

See here for more information: [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)