# Python tuple comparison odd behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

Can someone please explain this behavior?

```
In[11]: (1, 2) in [(True, 2)]
Out[11]: True

In[12]: (1, 2) in [(True, True)]
Out[12]: False

In[13]: (1, 2) in [(True, False)]
Out[13]: False

In[14]: ("1", 2) in [(True, 2)]
Out[14]: False
```

It feels like a bug--whenever I check if a tuple is in a list of tuples, the integer 1 is always equal to True. I don't want to report it to the Python bug tracker if it can be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something of an implementation detail of `True`, see [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante) for a discussion.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that answer, it has lots of useful information!

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" here I suppose is that `1 == True` and `0 == False` both evaluate to `True`.

Your lines `11`, `12` and `13` imply that all truthy values should be equal. If that were the case though, `1 == 2` would evaluate to `True` which would clearly be a bug.