# python tuple comparison, 'less than' revisited (2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I want to understand Python's behavior for tuple comparison operators, specifically **<** (the less-than operator).

---

edit: Now I get it, thank you Jaroslaw for a clear answer.

My error was thinking 1) "Lexicographical comparison" was a synonym for "string compare",
and 2) thinking that the "string compare logic" applied to each element of the tuples being compared instead of at the tuple-level.  Which yields valid behavior for **==** but not so much for **<**.

On the off chance anyone else gets stuck on the distinction.

> *excerpt from wikipedia (emphasis added)*[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order): ...lexicographical order ... is a **generalization** 
>   of the way the alphabetical order of words is based on the alphabetical order of their component letters.
>   This generalization consists primarily in defining a **total order** over the **sequences ...  of
>   elements of a finite totally ordered set**, often called alphabet.

original question text follows...

---

Wait, you say, hasn't this been asked before?
Yes... and pretty well answered for **==** (equality).
I want to understand why **( 1, 2 ) < ( 1, 3 )** yields **True** (note the **<** less than operator, code example below).  This is likely just a python-newbie error on my part, but I am having trouble finding it.

I've read some other questions about how tuple comparisons involves "lexicographic comparisons of the respective elements form each tuple."

**Question:** [python-tuple-comparison-odd-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586081/python-tuple-comparison-odd-behavior):  This question is about using the **in** operator, I'm interested in **<** (less than), not so much the behavior of **in** (at least not yet).

**Question:** [python-tuple-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/python-tuple-comparison):  For this one the answer says (emphasis added):

> *excerpt from Answer:* Tuples are compared position by position: the first item of first
>   tuple is compared to the first item of the second tuple; if they are
>   **not equal**, this is the result of the comparison, else the second item
>   is considered, then the third and so on.

Which I understand for **==** comparisons.
edit: *thought I understood

To generalize to all comparison operators I would modify the answer to be *something* like this:

> ... the first item of first tuple is compared to the
>   first item of the second tuple; if the comaprison yields False
>   then the result of the tuple comaprison is also False.  Otherwise
>   the comparison continues with the remaining items....
>   edit: this was wrong. Subtly wrong though, worked for **==** but not other relational operators.

I am having trouble seeing how that works for **<** (less than) comparisons.
The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) they link to (modified to point to 2.7) also talks about this in terms of equality, not less than - again, emphasis added:

> *excerpt from python docs:* Sequence types also support comparisons. In particular, tuples and
>   lists are compared lexicographically by comparing corresponding
>   elements. This means that to **compare equal**, every element must **compare
>   equal** and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same
>   length. (For full details see Comparisons in the language reference.)
>   edit: at this point when writing up my original question I had tunnel vision on 'equality'.

I found nothing helpful in the The Comparisons language reference; it doesn't touch on why **( 1, 2 ) < ( 1, 3 )** yields **True** when the comparison operator seems like it should yield False for the first pair of elements.

The following is some example output of a toy test program; *most* of it works as I would expect.  Please note the 2 embedded questions.

Ouput from "tcomp.py" (source below).

```
$ python tcomp.py
tcomp.py
version= 2.7.12

---  empty tuples, intuitive, no surprises  ---
()  ==  ()  :  True
()   <  ()  :  False
()   >  ()  :  False

---  single-item tuples, equal values: intuitive, no surprises  ---
(1,)  ==  (1,)  :  True
(1,)   <  (1,)  :  False
(1,)   >  (1,)  :  False

---  single-item diff: intuitive, no surprises  ---
(1,)  ==  (2,)  :  False
(1,)   <  (2,)  :  True
(1,)   >  (2,)  :  False

---  double-item same: intuitive, no surprises  ---
(1, 2)  ==  (1, 2)  :  True
(1, 2)   <  (1, 2)  :  False
(1, 2)   >  (1, 2)  :  False
* Question: do a<b and a>b both yield False 
* because Python short circuits on
* a[0] < b[0]    (and correspondingly a[0] > b[0] )?
* e.g. Python never bothers comparing second
* elements: a[1] < b[1]  (and, correspondinlgy, a[1] > b[1] ).

---  double-item 1st=same 2nd=diff: ??? What is with a<b ???
(1, 2)  ==  (1, 3)  :  False
(1, 2)   <  (1, 3)  :  True
(1, 2)   >  (1, 3)  :  False
* Question: Here I get the == comparison, that yields False like I would expect.
* But WHAT is going on with the < comparison?
* Even comapring "lexicographically", how does a[0] < b[0]
* actually yield True ?
* Is Python really  comparing a[0] < b[0] ?
* Because in my mental model that is the same as comparing: 1 < 1
* I kind of think 1 < 1 is supposed to be False, even if Python
* is comparing "1" < "1"  (e.g. lexicographically).
$
```

To add to the last "*Question" above, comapring **a[0] < b[0]** lexicographically would be like comparing **'1' < '1'** which still should be false, yes?

**tcomp.py:**

```
import platform

def tupleInfo( a, b, msg ):
   # using labels instead of eval-style stuff to keep things simpler.
   print
   print '--- ' , msg , ' ---'
   print a, ' == ', b, ' : ', a == b
   print a, '  < ', b, ' : ', a  < b
   print a, '  > ', b, ' : ', a  > b

print 'tcomp.py'
print 'version=', platform.python_version()

# let's start with some empty tuples.
e1 = tuple()
e2 = tuple()
tupleInfo( tuple( )         , tuple( )         , 'empty tuples,intuitive, no surprises' )
tupleInfo( tuple( [ 1 ] )   , tuple( [ 1 ] )   , 'single-item tuples, equal values: intuitive, no surprises' )
tupleInfo( tuple( [ 1 ] )   , tuple( [ 2 ] )   , 'single-item diff: intuitive, no surprises' )
tupleInfo( tuple( [ 1, 2 ] ), tuple( [ 1, 2 ] ), 'double-item same: intuitive, no surprises' )

print '* Question: do a<b and a>b both yield False '
print '* because Python short circuits on'
print '* a[0] < b[0]    (and correspondingly a[0] > b[0] )?'
print '* e.g. Python never bothers comparing second'
print '* elements: a[1] < b[1]  (and, correspondinlgy, a[1] > b[1] ).'


tupleInfo( tuple( [ 1, 2 ] ), tuple( [ 1, 3 ] ), 'double-item 1st=same 2nd=diff: ??? What is with a<b ???' )

print '* Question: Here I get the == comparison, that yields False like I would expect.'
print '* But WHAT is going on with the < comparison?'
print '* Even comapring "lexicographically", how does a[0] < b[0]'
print '* actually yield True ?'
print '* Is Python really  comparing a[0] < b[0] ?'
print '* Because in my mental model that is the same as comparing: 1 < 1'
print '* I kind of think 1 < 1 is supposed to be False, even if Python'
print '* is comparing "1" < "1"  (e.g. lexicographically).'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in word 'lexigographicly'. It means, that python compares tuples beginning from the first position. This order is used in vocabularies or lexicons - word *a* is smaller than word *b*, if *a* apperars in vocabulary before *b*. Then we can compare two words like `'anthrax'` and `'antipodes'`, where three first letters are equal: `'anthrax'` appears in vocabulary before `'antipodes'`, so the statement `'anthrax' < 'antipodes'` is `True`.

This comparision can be represented like this:

```
def isSmaller(a, b): # returns true if a<b, false if a>=b
    for i in xrange(0, a.__len__()): # for every elementof a, starting from left
        if b.__len__() <= i: # if a starts with b, but a is longer, eg. b='ab', a='ab...'
            return False
        if a[i] < b[i]: # if a starts like b, but there is difference on i-th position, 
                        # eg. a='abb...', b='abc...', 
            return True
        if a[i] > b[i]: # eg. a='abc...', b='abb...', 
            return False
        if a[i] == b[i]: # if there is no difference, check the next position
            pass
    if a.__len__() < b.__len__(): # if b starts with a, but b is longer, eg. a='ac', b='ac...'
        return True
    else: # else, ie. when a is the same as b, eg. a='acdc', b='acdc'
        return False


print (1,2,3)<(1,2)
print (1,2,3)<(1,2,3)
print (1,2,3)<(1,3,2)
print isSmaller((1,2,3),(1,2))
print isSmaller((1,2,3),(1,2,3))
print isSmaller((1,2,3),(1,3,2))
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
False
False
True
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear example!  You have improved my perspective. I was way too up close and getting stuck on "lexicographic compare" for each element (part) vs. the tuples (whole).