# How to make this statement true using python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make this statement to evaluate to be true using parentheses.
I have tried multiple combinations but it always evaluates out to be false

2 + 3 == 4 + 5 == 7

Comment: Please show what you've tried. This is an incredibly trivial question

Answer (score 4):

`False` is considered to be `0`, and `True` is considered to be `1`, so it should be:

`(2 + (3 == 4) + 5) == 7`

Since `False` is `0`, the `3 == 4` part would evaluate to `0`. Because of this, the expression would be the equivalent of:

`(2 + 0 + 5) == 7`

which would evaluate to `True`

Comment: Note that this only works properly in Python 3.x. See for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/5717099).

Comment: There should be no problem in Python 2.  Even overriding the built-in `False`: `__builtins__.False = 10;print int(3 == 4);print False` gives a zero for the comparison. Prints: `0` and `10`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMüller. Upon further testing, I got the same results (removed the disclaimer since it seems this won't be an issue)