# Using boolean values as array index in python

Tags: python, arrays, types

Why is it possible to use boolean values as index in python? e.g

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[True]
2
>>> a[False]
1
```

Since python is a strongly typed language, shouldn't the compiler throw a TypeError just like when adding a string and integer together? e.g.

```
>>> "1" + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cant convert 'int' object to 'str' implicitly
>>> 1 + "1"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Booleans subclass integers, as you can see from `isinstance(True, int)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is actually a subclass of `int`.  Just as every number is a boolean, every boolean is an integer.  If you use `int(True)`, you'll get `1` and if you do `int(False)`, you'll get `0`.  When you use `a[True]`, it's the same thing as `a[1]`.  You know that `bool` subclasses `int` from this test:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```