# Python: One liner for summing up elements in a list meeting a condition

Tags: python

How can I write this code python in one line?

```
num_positive_weights = 0
for i in  weights['value']:
    if i >= 0:
        num_positive_weights+=1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that's not valid Python code (the `i++` syntax isn't supported), but it would be as follows:

```
num_positive_weights = sum(i>=0 for i in weights['value'])
```

Comment: Please note that it is _not guaranteed_ for Python 2.x to return `1` for `True`.

Comment: @Selcuk - That's very true, but not relevant here, as I'm simply using [the comparison itself rather than `True`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante).

Answer (score 4):

```
num_positive_weights = len([i for i in weights['value'] if i >= 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num_positive_weights = sum(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, weights['value']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore `import` statements, you can write it as

```
import operator
num_positive_weights = reduce(operator.add, (1 for i in weights['value'] if i >= 0))
```

If `import` statements count, you can do

```
num_positive_weights = reduce(__import__("operator").add, (1 for i in weights['value'] if i >= 0))
```

or

```
num_positive_weights = reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, (1 for i in weights['value'] if i >= 0))
```

Or, to go deeper:

```
num_positive_weights = reduce(lambda a,b: a+1, filter(lambda i: i >= 0, weights['value']), 0)
```