# Is there any legitimate use of list[True], list[False] in Python?

Tags: python, boolean

Since `True` and `False` are instances of `int`, the following is valid in Python:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2]
>>> l[False]
0
>>> l[True]
1
```

I understand why this happens. However, I find this behaviour a bit unexpected and can lead to hard-to-debug bugs. It has certainly bitten me a couple of times.

Can anyone think of a legit use of indexing lists with `True` or `False`?

Comment: [Here's a bunch of examples](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/python-tricks/boolean-indices).

Comment: Useful for code golf : print(('ko', 'ok')[a<b])

Comment: It's valid python code, whether it's "legit" use is then mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: Interesting discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante

Comment: @skyking When I say 'legit' I mean an useful use case where there is likely no better, more readable and maintainable and less magical option in the language. Although I guess this last thing is also a matter of opinion. :)

Comment: @dukebody "better", "more readable", "maintainable" and "magical" are all matter of opinion...

Comment: Note that in numpy `ndarray`, it has a different meaning: `np.array([1, 2, 3])[array([True, False, True])]` → `array([1, 3])`.

Comment: This is far too opinion-based. Depending on your definition of "legit", the entire [PPCG.SE site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) may qualify - we exploit the fact that `False == 0` and `True == 1` regularly to write short code.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the past, some people have used this behaviour to produce a poor-man's [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator):

```
['foo', 'bar'][eggs > 5]  # produces 'bar' when eggs is 6 or higher, 'foo' otherwise
```

However, with a [proper conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) having been added to the language in Python 2.5, this is very much frowned upon, for the reasons you state: relying on booleans being a subclass of integers is too 'magical' and unreadable for a maintainer.

So, unless you are code-golfing (*deliberately* producing very compact and obscure code), use

```
'bar' if eggs > 5 else 'foo'
```

instead, which has the added advantage that the two expressions this selects between are *lazily* evaluated; if `eggs > 5` is false, the expression before the `if` is never executed.

Comment: but how does it actually work Martin? i tried list l = [2, 0, 1] just to see what it yields adn False returns 2 and True 0..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: `True == 1`, `False == 0`, because booleans are a subclass of `int`. Since `eggs > 5`  produces a boolean, but indexing takes the integer value, `eggs > 5` being `True` produces `['foo', 'bar'][1]`, otherwise `['foo', 'bar'][0]` is produced.

Comment: Is the alternative form still clearer if the entity you are indexing is verbose? `x = available_options[choice].response_text[ int(n<9) ]` maybe? I'd certainly argue for always putting that `int()` there to make it more readable, even though it's a no-op by language definitions.

Comment: @nigel222: I'd prefer `opts = available_options[choice].response_text`, and `x = opts[0] if n < 9 else opts[1]`.

Comment: Alternatively, I personally find a dict for mapping a lot easier to quickly scan over:  `{True: opts[0], False: opts[1]}[n < 9]`.  (Or if you want to get a bit crazier, `opts[ {True: 0, False: 1}[n < 9] ]`)

Comment: @Izkata: but again that negates the short-circuit behaviour. Why all the need for obscurity?

Comment: @MartijnPieters For clarity.  Taking advantage of this particular short-circuit is a C-like mentality, and takes more mental overhead.

Comment: @Izkata: I really don't find that clearer, and it is very much flying in the face of Python idiom.

Comment: Sorry, the C-like mentality I'm referring to is `int(True) == 1`, which I absolutely avoid.  If short-circuiting is actually necessary (say, there's a function call involved), then I'll use the ternary.  But my preference for the dict form is related to Python's way of trying to make everything sentence-like (`!` vs `not`, for example, and changing the order of the ternary) - it adds mental overhead parsing the line into a logic construction, where the symbolic way actually looks like the logic construction.

Answer (score 35):

If you are puzzled why `bool` is a valid index argument: this is simply for **consistency** with the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` and in Python it **is** a numerical type.

If you are asking why `bool` is a numerical type in the first place then you have to understand that `bool` wasn't present in old releases of Python and people used `int`s instead.

I will add a bit of historic arguments. First of all the addition of `bool` in python is shortly described in Guido van Rossum (aka BDFL) blogpost: [The History of Python: The history of `bool`, `True` and `False`](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/). The type was added via [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).

The PEP contains the *actual* rationales used for this decisions. I'll quote some of the portions of the PEP below.

> 4) Should we strive to eliminate non-Boolean operations on bools
>    in the future, through suitable warnings, so that for example
>    `True+1` would eventually (in Python 3000) be illegal?
>
> => No.
>
> There's a small but vocal minority that would prefer to see
>    "textbook" bools that don't support arithmetic operations at
>    all, but most reviewers agree with me that bools should always
>    allow arithmetic operations.

---

> 6) Should `bool` inherit from `int`?
>
> => Yes.
>
> In an ideal world, `bool` might be better implemented as a
>   separate integer type that knows how to perform mixed-mode
>   arithmetic.  However, **inheriting `bool` from `int` eases the
>   implementation enormously(in part since all C code that calls
>   `PyInt_Check()` will continue to work -- this returns true for
>    subclasses of `int`).**  Also, I believe this is right in terms of
>    substitutability: code that requires an `int` can be fed a `bool`
>    and it will behave the same as `0` or `1`.  Code that requires a
>    `bool` may not work when it is given an `int`; for example, 3 & 4
>    is 0, but both 3 and 4 are true when considered as truth
>    values.

---

> Because `bool` inherits from `int`, `True+1` is valid and equals `2`, and
>   so on.  **This is important for backwards compatibility**: because
>   comparisons and so on currently return integer values, there's no
>   way of telling what uses existing applications make of these
>   values.

---

> **Because of backwards compatibility**, the bool type lacks many
>    properties that some would like to see.  For example, arithmetic
>    operations with one or two bool arguments is allowed, treating
>    False as 0 and True as 1.  Also, a bool may be used as a sequence
>    index.
>
> **I don't see this as a problem, and I don't want evolve the
>    language in this direction either.  I don't believe that a
>    stricter interpretation of "Booleanness" makes the language any
>    clearer.**

---

**Summary**:

- Backwards compatibility: there was plenty of code that already used `int`s `0` and `1` to represent `False` and `True` and some of it used those values in numerical computations.
- It wasn't seen as a big deal to have a "non-textbook" `bool` type
- Plenty of people in the Python community wanted these features
- BDFL said so.

Answer (score 4):

There are often better ways, but Boolean indices do have their uses.  I've used them when I want to convert a boolean result to something more human readable:

```
test_result = run_test()
log.info("The test %s." % ('Failed', 'Passed')[test_result])
```