# Anonymous function managing function's outputs, without lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, functools

Say I have a function that returns a tuple of outputs:

```
def f():
    return 'zero', 1
```

But I have to supply in-line a new anonymous function that returns only e.g. the zeroth element of that returned tuple. This is an easy one-liner with a `lambda`:

```
lambda : f()[0]  # returns 'zero'
```

Is there a way to do the same thing using `functools` or similar?

Given that `lambda` was allegedly ['planned to [be removed] from Python 3, as one of "Python's glitches"'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252425/119775), I'm assuming there's a way to do this without `lambda`, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I know that `functools.partial` can pretty much be a substitute for `lambda` when managing a function's input arguments. But managing a function's outputs? Haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are perhaps looking for `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_zeroth = itemgetter(0)
assert get_zeroth(f()) == 'zero'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try behaviour to produce a [poor-man's conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117588)

```
print(f()[f()[0]==' '])
```

Since `[f()[0]!=' ']` produces a boolean , As you said it produce a tuple so `[f()[0]==' ']` will  always be wrong so it will give 0 which is index no which you want.

Answer (score 0):

The current answers appear to be producing the value itself -- which you seem to be content with achieving through `f()[0]` -- as opposed to a callable producing the value. Is lazy evaluation (as you have with your `lambda` example) a requirement? If not, the problem is no longer that of post-composing `f` with a projection but rather that of defining a constant function, and I'll nominate

```
itertools.repeat(f()[0]).__next__
```