# Reclassification by column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, array-broadcasting

I would like to apply a test to a pandas dataframe, and create flags in a corresponding dataframe based on the test results.  I've gotten this far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


matrix = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 11, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 22, 8, 9]})
flags = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(matrix.shape), columns=matrix.columns)
flag_values = pd.Series({"a": 100, "b": 200})

flags[matrix > 10] = flag_values
```

but this raises the error

```
ValueError: Must specify axis=0 or 1
```

Where can I specify the axis in this situation?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Edit:

The result I'm looking for in this example for "flags" is

```
a    b
0    0
100  0
0    200
0    0
0    0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define `flags = (matrix > 10) * flag_values`:

```
In [35]: (matrix > 10) * flag_values
Out[35]: 
     a    b
0    0    0
1  100    0
2    0  200
3    0    0
4    0    0
```

This relies on [True having numeric value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017/190597) and False having numeric value 0.
It also relies on Pandas' nifty [automatic alignment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures) of DataFrames (and Series) based on labels before performing arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 3):

`mask` with `mul`

```
flags.mask(matrix > 10,1).mul(flag_values,axis=1)

Out[566]: 
       a      b
0    0.0    0.0
1  100.0    0.0
2    0.0  200.0
3    0.0    0.0
4    0.0    0.0
```