# Python numpy: perform function on each pair of columns in a numpy 2-D array?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I'm trying to apply a function to each pair of columns in a numpy array (each column is an individual's genotype).

For example:

```
[48]: g[0:10,0:10]

array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
      [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
      [-1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
      [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]], dtype=int8)
```

My goal is to produce a distance matrix d so that each element of d is the pairwise distance comparing each column in g.

```
d[0,1] = func(g[:,0], g[:,1])
```

Any ideas would be fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: How does the distance function work?

Comment: It takes 2 numpy arrays to compare them: def count_snp_diffs(x, y):
    return np.count_nonzero((x != y) & (x >= 0) & (y >= 0)) . Courtesy of http://alimanfoo.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define the function as:

```
def count_snp_diffs(x, y): 
    return np.count_nonzero((x != y) & (x >= 0) & (y >= 0),axis=0)
```

And then call it using as index an array generated with `itertools.combinations`, in order to get *all* possible column combinations:

```
combinations = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(g.shape[1]),2)))
dist = count_snp_diffs(g[:,combinations[:,0]], g[:,combinations[:,1]])
```

In addition, if the output **must** be stored in a matrix (which for large `g` is not recomendes because only the upper triangle will be filled and all the rest will be useless info, this can be achieved with the same trick:

```
d = np.zeros((g.shape[1],g.shape[1]))
combinations = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(g.shape[1]),2)))
d[combinations[:,0],combinations[:,1]] = count_snp_diffs(g[:,combinations[:,0]], g[:,combinations[:,1]])
```

Now, `d[i,j]` returns the distance between columns `i` and `j` (whereas `d[j,i]` is a zero). This approach relies in the fact that arrays can be indexed with lists or arrays containing repeated indexes:

```
a = np.arange(3)+4
a[[0,1,1,1,0,2,1,1]]
# Out
# [4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5]
```

Here is one step by step explanation of what is happening.

Calling `g[:,combinations[:,0]]` accesses all the columns in the first clumn of permutations, generating a new array, which is compared column by column with the array generated with `g[:,combinations[:,1]]`. Thus, A boolean array `diff` is generated. If `g` had 3 columns it would look like this, where each column is the comparison of columns `0,1`, `0,2` and `1,2`:

```
[[ True False False]
 [False  True False]
 [ True  True False]
 [False False False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```

And finally, the values for each column are added:

```
np.count_nonzero(diff,axis=0)
# Out
# [2 3 0]
```

In addition, due to the fact that the boolean class in python inherits from integer class (roughly `False==0` and  and `True==1`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/2504700) of *"Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?"* for more info). The `np.count_nonzero` adds 1 for each `True` position, which is the same result obtained with `np.sum`:

```
np.sum(diff,axis=0) 
# Out
# [2 3 0]
```

### Notes on performance and memory

For large arrays, working with the whole array at a time can require too much memory and you can get a `Memory Error`, however, for small or medium arrays, it tends to be the fastest approach. In some cases it can be useful to work by chunks:

```
combinations = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(g.shape[1]),2)))
n = len(combinations)
dist = np.empty(n)
# B = np.zeros((g.shape[1],g.shape[1]))
chunk = 200
for i in xrange(chunk,n,chunk):
    dist[i-chunk:i] = count_snp_diffs(g[:,combinations[i-chunk:i,0]], g[:,combinations[i-chunk:i,1]])
    # B[combinations[i-chunk:i,0],combinations[i-chunk:i,1]] = count_snp_diffs(g[:,combinations[i-chunk:i,0]], g[:,combinations[i-chunk:i,1]])
dist[i:] = count_snp_diffs(g[:,combinations[i:,0]], g[:,combinations[i:,1]])
# B[combinations[i:,0],combinations[i:,1]] = count_snp_diffs(g[:,combinations[i:,0]], g[:,combinations[i:,1]])
```

For `g.shape=(300,N)`, the execution times reported by `%%timeit` in my computer with python 2.7, numpy 1.14.2 and allel 1.1.10 are:

- 10 columns

  - numpy + matrix storage: 107 µs
  - numpy + 1D storage : 101 µs
  - allel : 247 µs
- 100 columns

  - numpy + matrix storage: 15.7 ms
  - numpy + 1D storage : 16 ms
  - allel : 22.6 ms
- 1000 columns

  - numpy + matrix storage: 1.54 s
  - numpy + 1D storage : 1.53 s
  - allel : 2.28 s

With these array dimensions, pure numpy is a litle faster than allel module, but the computation time should be checked for the dimensions in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your expected pairs using `np.dstack` and then apply the function on third axis using `np.apply_along_axis`.

```
new = np.dstack((arr[:,:-1], arr[:, 1:]))
np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 2, new)
```

Example :

```
In [86]: arr = np.array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
    ...:        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
    ...:        [-1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
    ...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]], dtype=np.int8)
    ...:        
    ...:        

In [87]: new = np.dstack((arr[:,:-1], arr[:, 1:]))

In [88]: new
Out[88]: 
array([[[ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1, -1]],

    ...

In [89]: 

In [89]: np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 2, new)
Out[89]: 
array([[ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  0,  0,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  0],
       [-2, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions!
I've just been told that this is possible with scikit-allel: https://scikit-allel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ where you can define your own distance matrix to be performed on pairwise combinations of columns in a 2-D numpy array:

`dist = allel.pairwise_distance(g, metric=count_snp_diffs)`

Thank you for your help!

http://alimanfoo.github.io/2016/06/10/scikit-allel-tour.html

Comment: Oh! Now I understand properly the desired output. I will edit my answer. A priori, I expect `numpy` to be a little faster, I don't know if this is an important factor for you

Comment: I have edited the answer. There is some analysis of the computation time spent by each of them, however, you should check that with your `g` array, if it is really large, you may get `Memory Error` or end up being slower using numpy