# And statement for boolean and non boolean columns in pandas susprisingly yields a result

Tags: pandas

I am "anding" a binary and non binary column in a pandas DataFrame. To my surprise, this actually gave a result (I was expecting an error). Take a look at the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1':[1,1,2,2,2], 'col2':[3,4,4,4,3]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
test_df['bool1'] = [True, False, True, True, False]
test_df['bool2'] = [True, False, True, True, True]
test_df['col3'] = [1,3,3,5,5]
test_df['col3'] & test_df['bool1']
```

I get the following result:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

How does pandas evaluate this? `col3` is not boolean/binary so I have a hard time determining what drives the decision on whether the combination of both is `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are casted `0` to `False` and another integers to `True`s:

```
d = {'col1':[1,1,2,2,2], 'col2':[3,4,4,4,3]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
test_df['bool1'] = [True, False, True, True, False]
test_df['bool2'] = [True, False, True, True, True]
#changed first value to 0
test_df['col3'] = [0,3,3,5,5]

print (test_df['col3'] & test_df['bool1'])
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

It working like casted by `astype`:

```
print (test_df['col3'].astype(bool))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: col3, dtype: bool
```

Next reading - [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017)