# why does this function return non negative numbers?

Tags: python

```
In [20]: def relu(x): 
    ...:     return (x>0) * x 
    ...:
```

Is that because in Python, True is interpreted as 1 while False as 0 implicitly?

Comment: Yes in Python 3, "no" in Python 2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/831878

Comment: That's great and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`False` is just a keyword that means `int` equal to `0`. Same for `True` and `1`.