# Why do these shorthands not work with each other?

Tags: python

I was wondering how to take advantage of shorthand notation of if-else and `+=` in Python of this simple expression:

I tried to set brackets everywhere and changed `+=` to `*=` which didn't change the situation of course.

This works as expected:

```py
a, b = 0, True
for i in range(123):
     if b == True:
          a = a + 1
```

Still working as expected, trying shorthand of if-else led me to:

```
a, b = 0, True
for i in range(123):
     a = a + 1 if b == True else a
```

Finally the attempt to write:

```
a, b = 0, True
for i in range(123):
     a += 1 if b == True else a:
```

fails and surprisingly I get pretty quickly huge integers for `a`

Moreover I'd really like something more shorthanded, e.g.:

```
a, b = 0, True
for i in range(123):
     a += 1 if b
```

The for-loop needs to stay as it is, since in my case there are other operations that affect `b`.

Comment: `a += 1 if b else 0`?

Comment: ty for so many answers within the last 2 hours btw. ;-)

all of them were very helpful too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To closest to your proal is probably:

```
a, b = 0, True
for i in range(123):
   a += b
```

Since `bool` is a subtype of int, no conversion is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Since noone seems to be posting, **why** it goes like this, here is mine - lines:

```
a = a + 1 if b == True else a
a += 1 if b == True else a
```

are seen by python as:

```
a = (a + 1 if b == True else a)
a += (1 if b == True else a)
```

This is why you get large numbers fast in second version - you will add `a` to `a`, when `b` is `False`. If you want to keep the `if`, then go:

```
a += (1 if b else 0)
```

Also don't compare `b` to `True` (or `False), go fo`if b`, as it's more pythonic (it will prevent some weird mistakes, when other code will start to interact with yours).

EDIT: go for @Tomerikoo answer for even shorter code, but keep in mind, that those waters can be muddy and not everyone knows / easily follows, that adding boolean to int treats first as 1 (or 0 if `False`).

Comment: ty for this extensive answer, since i want to assure that b is a boolean I consider comparing it with a boolean is the best way, am i wrong?

Comment: booleans are not *converted* to ints, they simply *are*. Look at my answer for examples. @shorthand_fan, you are not wrong in your approach, it is just not pythonic, let's say, to write `b == True` as simply checking for `b` will do. There are other ways for assuring `b` is bool but what you did is not wrong. I would however change to `b is True`

Comment: python's `boolean` is it's own type, therefore i'd say it's not integer. I'd have to dig thru python's source code, but i'm willing to hazard a guess, that there's a shortcut (or maybe straight `__mul__` operator, that when taken with int and bool does the magic.

Comment: yep, exactly what I meant. as you can see in my answer, bools are actually sub-class of int, where `True` has the value of 1 and `False` has the value of 0. So no conversion is actually needed and, as you said, the dunder functions take care of it by implementation. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/6045800) for more detailed (interesting) explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
for i in range(123):
     if b:a+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```py
for i in range(123):
    a = a + 1*b
```

Because booleans **are** ints:

```py
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

Comment: While this is clever (i didn't knew i can multiply boolean with int and get away in python and i use python for like 10 years) this is also hard to read. `1 * b` is pretty much `b` to everyone and someone will sooner or later try to refactor the code by removing multiplication.

Comment: True, also can be shorthanded to `+=`. My intention was to show how the condition is still there and to make it more general. Say, if tomorrow OP will want to add `c` to `a` if `b` is True (so it will be `c*b`)

Answer (score 1):

just note that

```
a += x if condition else y
```

will resolve to `a += x` if the `condition` is `True`; otherwise it will be `a += y`. this is why your numbers get big...

apart from that i suggest you use what [U10-Forward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107088/4954037) suggests.