# Why "0" and '0' are evaluated to False?

Tags: python

I was thinking if we were checking the boolean of string or character, we were checking if they were empty.  But the following code gave me unexpected outputs.

```
print('0'==True)
print("0"==True)
```

Output:

```
False
False
```

What is happening? What we were really checking?

Comment: They are not `False`. You are comparing strings to the literal `True`

Comment: That's not testing truthiness, that's just equality to the value `True`. Try `bool('0')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are true (in a boolean context):

```
if '0':
    print("you will see this")
if '': # for comparison
    print("you will not see this")
# Alternately:
bool('0') # True
bool('') # False
```

But they are not *equal to* the special value `True`.

There is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You must be thinking of languages that convert operands to a common type before checking for equality. This is not how Python works. As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons), the rules for equality are pretty complex; but they boil down to this:

> The default behavior for equality comparison (== and !=) is based on the identity of the objects.

So all non-empty strings are ["interpreted as true"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) (as are most objects, other than empty containers and a couple of constants); but they are not equal to each other, and they are not equal to the constant `True`.

"Interpreted as true" basically means that they make a conditional come out true, and that conversion to boolean (with `bool()`) will give the value `True`.

PS. Just for fun, note that the following *does* hold:

```
>>> print(1 == True)
True
```

Yes, the constant `True` just happens to be [equal to the integer `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante). Why not?

Answer (score 0):

if you compare this:

```
print('0'==False) # False
print("0"==False) # False
```

so they are not giving false, you are comparing if a '0' is equal to True which is false but if you are doing something like

```
if '0':
   print("true") # this will be printed
```

Answer (score 0):

`'0'` is a string, which is not empty. For strings, only empty string is falsy i.e. `''`:

```
In [239]: bool('0')                                                                  
Out[239]: True

In [240]: bool('')                                                            
Out[240]: False
```

And for truthy/falsey test, you can just do:

```
if <some_value>:
```

no need to check against any other value. This is applicable for all types.