# Accessing numpy array with list of logical indices prints the list instead

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

When using logical indexing on numpy arrays, different behaviours occur based on whether the indices were boolean or integer (1/0). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/4443082) states that, as of Python 3.x,

> `True` and `False` are keywords and will always be equal to `1` and `0`.

Can someone explain what causes this behaviour?

MWE to replicate (Python 3.7.3, Numpy 1.16.3):

```
import numpy as np

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
c = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

npa = np.asarray(a)
npb = np.asarray(b)
npc = np.asarray(c)

print(npa[b])   # [0 1 2 3 4]
print(npa[npb]) # [0 1 2 3 4]
print(npa[c])   # [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
print(npa[npc]) # [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: `c` is just selecting the `a[0]` or `a[1]`.  It's a regular numeric index, not boolean.  In 'boolean' contexts, 0/1 have False/True meanings, but this isn't one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at it like this:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True]
c = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1]

npa = np.asarray(a)
npb = np.asarray(b)
npc = np.asarray(c)

print(npa[b])   # [0 1 2 3 4 9]
print(npa[npb]) # [0 1 2 3 4 9]
print(npa[c])   # [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 9]
print(npa[npc]) # [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 9]
```

We can see that `b` and `npb` are boolean masks that instruct which indices to choose and `c` and `npc` are actual indices to be taken from the given array.

This is mentioned in [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

> Boolean arrays used as indices are treated in a different manner
>   entirely than index arrays ... Unlike in the case of integer index
>   arrays, in the boolean case, the result is a 1-D array containing all
>   the elements in the indexed array corresponding to all the true
>   elements in the boolean array.