# Moving Zeros To The End: Why does my Python Code fail the test in CodeWars?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, optimization

**Problem**

**Link to the problem:** https://www.codewars.com/kata/52597aa56021e91c93000cb0/train/python

Write an algorithm that takes an array and moves all of the zeros to the end, preserving the order of the other elements.

`move_zeros([false,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]) # returns[false,1,1,2,1,3,"a",0,0]`

**My code:**

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    zero_count = array.count(0)
    array1 = list(filter(lambda a: a != 0, array)) + [0 for i in range(zero_count)]
    return array1
```

**Sample Tests:**

```py
Test.describe("Basic tests")
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1]),[ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]),[9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a",0,0,"b","c","d",0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]),["a","b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]),["a","b",None,"c","d",1,False,1,3,[],1,9,{},9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([0,1,None,2,False,1,0]),[1,None,2,False,1,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a","b"]),["a","b"])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a"]),["a"])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([0,0]),[0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([0]),[0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([False]),[False])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([]),[])
```

**My Output after running:**

- Test Passed
- Test Passed
- Test Passed
- **['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] should equal ['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, False, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]**
- **[1, None, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0] should equal [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]**
- Test Passed
- Test Passed
- Test Passed
- Test Passed
- Test Passed
- Test Passed

**My Question:**

Why does my answer fail the 2 tests?

Comment: Just swap in a loop, and keep track the last non-zero position.

Comment: @EricWang Thank you very much for the idea :) Please provide a solution with code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving Zeros To The End: Failing the test in CodeWars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661462/moving-zeros-to-the-end-failing-the-test-in-codewars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the values `True` and `False` behave as equivalent to `1` and `0` when compared to integers. See the section under `numbers.Integral` in the [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.8/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy).  This means that when counting the zeroes, `False` will be counted as well, and in the lambda:

```py
lambda a: a != 0
```

The comparison of `a != 0` will filter out both `0` and `False`. One way to correct this is to modify the count to also be a filter, and to check in both lambdas that `a` is not a boolean:

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    zero_list = list(filter(lambda a: a == 0 and not isinstance(a, bool), array))
    array1 = list(filter(lambda a: a != 0 or isinstance(a, bool), array)) + zero_list
    return array1
```

Comment: Could you please update my code? It would be helpful :)

Comment: Updated the code and explanation to also include the count, since `count(0)` would count both zeroes and `False` values.

Answer (score 0):

Because you just drop out all `False`s in `a != 0`. `False` is 0 and 0 is `False`.

Further details: [Is False == 0 and True == 1 an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the)

Answer (score 0):

change all values a string and then perform the function

Comment: Nice idea. But still I would prefer a solution with code

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
def move_zeros(array):
    zero_count = array.count(0)
    array1 = list(filter(lambda a: a != 0 or isinstance(a, bool), array)) + [0 for i in range(zero_count)]
    return array1
```

Comment: That didn't work. Please add the code after testing

Comment: ['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, False, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] should equal ['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, False, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0, 0] should equal [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer and it works.  I just don't understand how it works.

```
def move_zeros(a):
    a.sort(key=lambda v: v == 0)
    return a
```