# Moving Zeros To The End: Failing the test in CodeWars?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, optimization

**Problem**

Link to the problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52597aa56021e91c93000cb0/train/python

Write an algorithm that takes an array and moves all of the zeros to the end, preserving the order of the other elements.

`move_zeros([false,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]) # returns[false,1,1,2,1,3,"a",0,0]`

**My code:**

```
def move_zeros(array):
    list = []
    list2 = []
    for n in array:
        if n is 0:
            list2.append(n)
        else:
            list.append(n)
    return list + list2
```

**Sample Tests:**

```
Test.describe("Basic tests")
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1]),[ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]),[9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a",0,0,"b","c","d",0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]),["a","b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]),["a","b",None,"c","d",1,False,1,3,[],1,9,{},9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([0,1,None,2,False,1,0]),[1,None,2,False,1,0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a","b"]),["a","b"])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros(["a"]),["a"])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([0,0]),[0,0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([0]),[0])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([False]),[False])
Test.assert_equals(move_zeros([]),[])
```

**My output:**

- Teste Passed
- **[9, 0.0, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] should equal [9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]**
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed
- Teste Passed

**My Question:**

I believe it fails because 0.0 is not 0. But I'm struggling to understand how can i write that.
I'm begining coding so my code doesn't look pythonic but i guess that's something I must pratice

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
n == 0 and n is not False
```

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

> There are three distinct numeric types: integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. In addition, Booleans are a subtype of integers

and

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal

Answer (score 0):

Just use `==` instead of `is`. `0 is 0.0` returns `False`, but `0 == 0.0` returns `True`.

Comment: If I do that, whenever "False" shows in other tests, python considers `False == 0`and then the code won't work either.  Example: (teste number 4)

['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] should equal ['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, False, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Ah, so `False` shouldn't be moved? In ths case, use `n == 0 and type(n) in (int, float)`

Comment: Better exclude `False` specifically: there are several numeric types (`numpy` has more), and you probably want to support all of them. `n == 0 and n is not False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if n is 0 or n == 0.0 and type(n) == float`. (or `type(0.0)` instead of `float`)

I dont know why `if n is 0 or n is 0.0` doesn't work. If anyone does, please comment.

Comment: Can you explain why, in the test number 6, when in the loop `n=False`, `True` is returned in the condition `if n == 0`but returns `False` if the condition is `if n is 0`

Comment: See One Lyner's answer. `False` is a boolean which in Python are a subtype of integers, so `False` can be compared to `0`, but it *is* not `0`.

Comment: @anatolyg Right... I figured it was because float values were not shared the same way integer values are. I'm guessing `n is 0` wouldn't be guaranteed to work either then.