# What does this expression with a boolean list index do?

Tags: python

I was solving some algorithm problems and in one of the solutions saw this expression, but can't figure out what does.

```
return [b, a][nums.count(a) > len(nums)//2]
```

In case the whole code is needed

```
def majorityElement6(self, nums):
    if not nums:
        return None
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums[0]
    a = self.majorityElement(nums[:len(nums)//2])
    b = self.majorityElement(nums[len(nums)//2:])
    if a == b:
        return a
    return [b, a][nums.count(a) > len(nums)//2]
```

Comment: There are more than half the amount in nums is a, return a; else return b

Comment: It creates a list with two elements, then indexes into that list with an expression that always produces 0 or 1 (thus being a valid index for the list).

Comment: `[b, a]` is a list with two elements, meaning that the valid indices are 0 and 1. `nums.count(a) > len(nums//2)` is a boolean expression that can be either `True` or `False`. I 'll let you figure out the rest.

Comment: Maybe this is written like that for historical reasons, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Answer (score 0):

A comparison like `>` returns a boolean, where [`False == 0` and `True == 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the).

The clearer way to write this is as a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
return a if nums.count(a) > len(nums)//2 else b
```