# Can we assign the assigned variables for a variable in python?

Tags: python

I have the below python code. I am unable to understand that how the result prints the x value as
true, and the Z value as false. And a as 11 and b as 10.

```
x = (1 == True)  
y = (2 == False)  
z = (3 == True)  
a = True + 10  
b = False + 10  

print("x is", x)  
print("y is", y)  
print("z is", z)  
print("a:", a)  
print("b:", b)
```

Comment: Hello, see this answer for details: "True and False are keywords and will always be equal to 1 and 0" https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764099/11547576

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what True and False are made of

```
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
>>> type(False)
<class 'bool'>
>>> bool.__bases__
(<class 'int'>,)
```

True and False are `bool` type which itself is a specialization of `int`. And they  behave like the integers 1 and 0.

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

But unlike regular variables, you can't assign anything to them. That's because they are also python language [Keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and the compiler won't allow the names "True" and "False" to be variables.

```
>>> True = 10
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to True
>>>
```

In your examples, `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`, so

```
This...       is the same as...  resulting in...
1 == True     1 == 1             True
2 == False    2 == 1             False
3 == True     3 == 1             False  
True + 10     1 + 10             11  
False + 10    0 + 10             10
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, True = 1, False = 0, so x=(1==True) means x = True if 1==1 else False.

For z, z=(3==True) means z=(3==1). 3 doesn't equal 1, so z = False.

For a, a=True+10 means a = 1+10=11.
For b, b=False+10 means b=0+10=10.

Comment: It should be `True =1` and `False = 0`.