# How do I in Python not evaluate 0 or 1 as True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
[2, 5, True, 1, 0, 4, False, False, True]
```

How do I make 1 and 0 show up as 1 and 0 as opposed to True and False?  I'm trying to do:

```
[True if X == True else False for X in list]
```

Desired result is:

```
[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `[x is True for x in lst]` ?

Comment: Related (or a duplicate...): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because 1 and 0 are "truthy" and "falsey" respectively. You can get around it by using `is` which uses the underlying singletons for True and False:

```
[True if X is True else False for X in list]
```

**Edit:** as noted in the comments, it's actually more correct to say that True is "1-like" and False "0-like" in some sense because of the underlying implementation. Less catchy than truthy & falsey though!

Comment: Actually, it's not because of truthiness. E.g. `[] == True` is false. This is because `bool` is a subclass of `int` with exactly two integers: 1, and 0, i.e. True and False

Comment: Good answer.  Thanks.  Answered based on format given as opposed to being too creative.

Comment: @user38283 Out of all the answers, you picked the one that matches your beginner style of code, no criticism implied here. However with getting a little more creative, you get answers that don't perform a whole bunch of unnecessary checks.

Comment: The answer fit my problem.  I could very well have another situation where I don't want a resulting vector of only True False (maybe True and other items), so other answers wouldn't apply.  The answer allows me to customize it for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type check:

```
[isinstance(X, bool) and X for X in list]
```

NB: the type check should come first, to ensure the expression always evaluates to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Type of the element by `isinstance(X, bool)`

So your code will be like this

```
[True if X == True and isinstance(X, bool)  else False for X in list]
```