# Pandas: Appending a row of boolean values to df using `loc` changes to `int`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

Consider `df`:

```
In [2098]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})

In [2099]: df
Out[2099]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Now, I try to append a `list` of values to `df`:

```
In [2102]: df.loc[2] = [3, 4]

In [2103]: df
Out[2103]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  4
```

All's good so far.

But now when I try to append a row with list of boolean values, it converts it into `int`:

```
In [2104]: df.loc[3] = [True, False]

In [2105]: df
Out[2105]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  4
3  1  0
```

I know I can convert my `df` into `str` and can then append boolean values, like:

```
In [2131]: df = df.astype(str)
In [2133]: df.loc[3] = [True, False]

In [2134]: df
Out[2134]: 
      a      b
0     1      3
1     2      4
3  True  False
```

But, I want to know the reason behind this behaviour. Why is it not automatically changing the `dtypes` of columns to `object` when I append `boolean` to it?

My Pandas version is:

```
In [2150]: pd.__version__
Out[2150]: '1.1.0'
```

Comment: `'1.1.0'` is my pandas version.

Comment: The boolean are ints (at least in standard Python). If you do df.loc[2] = ['3', '4'], it will change it to object.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, I know if I append list of string values, dtypes changes to `object`. Not sure why this behaviour is not replicated with `boolean`.

Comment: In my opinion mixing types are not recommended, so it should working buggy. Same problem if use `df.append(pd.Series([True, False], index=['a','b']), ignore_index=True )`

Comment: @MayankPorwal Because as I said in Python (not sure if pandas and numpy do the same)  the boolean are a subclass of integers: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the

Comment: Agreed with Dani , since python booleans are binary ints: `1+True` returns `2`, same way it returns a binary int when you add `True` and `False`

Comment: @jezrael Yes, same problem with series also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why is it not automatically changing the dtypes of columns to object when I append boolean to it?

Because the type are being *upcasted* (see [upcasting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#upcasting)), from the documentation:

> Types can potentially be upcasted when combined with other types,
> meaning they are promoted from the current type (e.g. int to float).

Upcasting works according to *numpy rules*:

> Upcasting is always according to the numpy rules. If two different
> dtypes are involved in an operation, then the more general one will be
> used as the result of the operation.

To understand how the *numpy rules* are applied you can use the function [find_common_type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.find_common_type.html), as below:

```
res = np.find_common_type([bool, np.bool], [np.int32, np.int64])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `df.loc[0]` it converts into an `pd.Series`, as shown below:

```
>>> type(df.loc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

And now, Series will only have a single `dtype`. So it coerces the `bool`eans to integers.

So the way to fix is to use `df.loc[[0]]` if you are trying to get the rows:

```
>>> type(df.loc[[0]])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

But in this case, you need to create 2 new empty rows then add the values with `df.loc[[...]]` because `df.loc[[...]]` is only for indexing, you can't assign new rows with that.

So here is how you can get the rows with `df.loc[[...]]`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
>>> df.loc[0]
a    1
b    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[[0]]
   a  b
0  1  3
>>>
```

Here you see the difference, the first code converts to a `Series` with only one `dtype` whereas the second code gives a `DataFrame`.

But for this case you can't use the `df.loc[[...]]`, since you can't assign things with that, so you only can go with creating new empty rows then using `df.loc[[...]]`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>> df.loc[2] = [3, 4]
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  4
>>> df.loc[3] = 0
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  4
3  0  0
>>> df.loc[[3]] = [True, False]
>>> df
      a      b
0     1      3
1     2      4
2     3      4
3  True  False
>>>
```