# why same index is being shown by python in this tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, tuples

in:  my_tuple=('a',9,1,True,'a', [2,5])

in:  my_tuple.index(1), my_tuple.index(True)

out: (2, 2)

can anyone explain what exactly is going on? Why index of the entry True and 1 are displayed the same?

Comment: It's because [1 == True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017/674039) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Since `True == 1`:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> (1, True,).index(True)
0
```

`bool` subclasses from `int` in Python, and in Python 3.x, you will always have `False = 0` and `True = 1`.

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> int(True)
1
```