# How the short if with array works in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can someone explain me how this syntax works in Python?
How is this expression being evaluated?

```
b = False
a = ['123', '456'][b == True]
print(a) => 123

b = True
a = ['123', '456'][b == True]
print(a) => 456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python [booleans can implicitly be converted to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the) where `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`. You can see it more clearly in this example:

```
>>> ["foo", "bar"][True]
'bar'
>>> ["foo", "bar"][False]
'foo'
```

Since `b == True` returns a boolean its value can also be interpreted as either `0` or `1`. `['123', '456'][b == True]` simply returns the `0`th or `1`st element of the list depending on the value of `b`.

That being said, this is an obfuscated and unreadable way of writing conditionals. Prefer the proper ternary expression:

```
a = '123' if b else '456'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation it's perfectly clear for me (and for the grammar correction)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Selcuk's answer:

This is also an list indexing question. Let's make replace the values of `False` and `True` with its boolean equivalent `0` and `1`. We will also solve for those booleans expression in the brackets.

```
>>> b = 0
>>> a = ['123', '456'][0]  # [b == True] is [0 == 1] is [False] 
>>> print(a)
'123'

>>> b = 1
>>> a = ['123', '456'][1]  # [b == True] is [1 == 1] is [True]
>>> print(a)
'456'
```

This looks far less intimidating. The first `a` wants the value of index `0` which is `123`. The second `a` wants the value of index `1` which is `456`.

You can try it out with a larger array to confirm:

```
>>> a = ['123','456','789'][2]
>>> a
'789'
```

More info on Python lists [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp).

Comment: Correction: These are lists, not arrays. Python [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) are different.

Comment: Thanks, i understand !

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that! Those are lists, not arrays. I even linked a Python list resource too lol. Edited.