# How can I define NA values in a list and check pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe, a value should be classed as missing if it is "nan", 0 or "missing".

I wrote a list

```
null_values = ["nan", 0, "missing"]
```

Then I checked which columns contained missing values

```
df.columns[df.isin(null_values).any()]
```

My df looks as follows:

```
{'Sick': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: True},
'Name': {0: 'Liam',
1: 'Chloe',
2: 'Andy',
3: 'Max',
4: 'Anne',
5: nan,
6: 'Charlie'},
'Age': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 9.0}}
```

It flags the column 'Sick' as containing missing values even though it only contains FALSE/TRUE values.  However, it correctly recognises that Age has no missing values.  Why does it count FALSE as a missing value when I have not defined it as such in my list?

Comment: `0` equals `False` in Python

Comment: As @DaniMesejo said , 0 equals False and 1 equals True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is exclude boolean columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
null_values = ["nan", 0, "missing"]


df1 = df.select_dtypes(exclude=bool)
print (df1.columns[df1.isin(null_values).any()])
Index([], dtype='object')
```

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the).

If need also compare `NaN` missing values add it to `list`:

```
null_values = ["nan", 0, "missing", np.nan]

df1 = df.select_dtypes(exclude=bool)
print (df1.columns[df1.isin(null_values).any()])
Index(['Name'], dtype='object')
```

EDIT: One trick is convert all values to strings, then need compare `'0'` for strings from integers and `'0.0'` for strings from floats:

```
null_values = ["nan", '0', '0.0', "missing"]

print (df.columns[df.astype(str).isin(null_values).any()])
Index(['Name'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: But is there anyway of checking a boolean column for numeric 0 values?