# How to distinguish between 1 and True (equivalently, 0 and False)?

Tags: python

The following code block raises the aforementioned question:

```
L1 = [1, True, 0, False]*5
L2 = [True, 1, False, 0]*5
D1 = dict(zip(L1, range(len(L1))))
D2 = dict(zip(L2, range(len(L2))))


print(L1) # [1, True, 0, False, 1, True, 0, False, 1, True, 0, False, 1, True, 0, False, 1, True, 0, False]
print(D1) # {1: 17, 0: 19}
print(L2) # [True, 1, False, 0, True, 1, False, 0, True, 1, False, 0, True, 1, False, 0, True, 1, False, 0]
print(D2) # {True: 17, False: 19}

#print(True in D1)
#print(0 in D2)
#print(True == 1)
#print(False == 0)
```

I can understand that being a subclass of `int` this is the expected behavior of `bool`. But does that not affect the structure of `list`?

How can I handle their (`1 and 0` or `True and False`) explicit presence in any case?
i.e. I want something like: `{1 : 16, True : 17, 0 : 18, False : 19}` (in case of `D1`), in a pure pythonic way.

Comment: maybe you could convert them to strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is False == 0 and True == 1 an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the)

Comment: What's the use case for distinguishing between the boolean values and their integer counterparts?

Comment: @chepner an example might be like: to count their number in a list.

Comment: @Tomerikoo well, I read it, that explains the situation that I know but doesn't show any way about what I want.

Comment: @CozyCode but that will change their `type` which I want to avoid.

Comment: @ApuCoder Part of my question is: why would you be mixing numbers and boolean values in the list in the first place?

Comment: Dict keys (or set elements) must be unique. `True` and `1` are not unique, because `True == 1`. (similar: int 1 and float 1.0 are equal) You cannot compare the situation with list/tuple items that have no such limitation. To distinguish you could use a 2-tuple as a key `(type(x),x)` (instead of `x`)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Gathering ideas from the comments* to an answer:</sup>

---

You seem to be aware of it, but the reason this happens is because [`True == 1` and `False == 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the). This means that as dict keys they will be mapped as equal and there can be no repeating keys.

To overcome this:

1. You could convert the keys to strings:

   ```py
   L1 = [1, True, 0, False]*5
   D1 = dict(zip(map(str, L1), range(len(L1))))

   print(D1)
   ```

   Will give:

   ```
   {'1': 16, 'True': 17, '0': 18, 'False': 19}
   ```

   But this has the downside of not being able to to actually tell the type of the key. You could overcome this by using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) when reading the dict:

   ```py
   import ast

   for key, value in D1.items():
       key = ast.literal_eval(key)
       print(key, type(key))
   ```

   Will give:

   ```
   1 <class 'int'>
   True <class 'bool'>
   0 <class 'int'>
   False <class 'bool'>
   ```

---

2. Change the keys of the dict to be ***tuples*** of the value and its type:

   ```py
   L1 = [1, True, 0, False]*5
   D1 = dict(zip(zip(L1, [type(x) for x in L1]), range(len(L1))))

   print(D1)
   ```

   Will give:

   ```
   {(1, <class 'int'>): 16, (True, <class 'bool'>): 17, (0, <class 'int'>): 18, (False, <class 'bool'>): 19}
   ```

   And when reading the dict you can get the 0-index element of the keys to get the actual *real* value.

---

<sup>* [converting to string idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316668/why-doesnt-python-distinguish-between-1-and-true-equivalently-0-and-false/70361313#comment124299972_70316668) by [CozyCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13984609/cozycode). [Adding the type to the key idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316668/why-doesnt-python-distinguish-between-1-and-true-equivalently-0-and-false/70361313#comment124301145_70316668) by [VPfB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378816/vpfb)</sup>