# Why dictionary first key 1 is not printing and length is showing three?? python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

This is my program.I can not print key 1 and lenght is showing 3 .What is the problem.

```py
pairs = {
    1: "apple",
    "orange": [2,3,4],
    True : False,
    12: "True",
    } 
#key Call 
print(pairs[1])

#Dictionary len() check
print(len(pairs))
```

The output I am getting .Please help anyone.

```py
False
3
```

Comment: Try to `print({1: "xxx", True: "xxx"})`. The dictionary will have only one element.

Comment: No "problem" but `True` simply ***is*** `1` which means the two overwrite each other in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Because true is 1 for python. When you assign false to True, it means you assign false to 1.

On the other hand, the **keys must be unique in the dictionary**. So when you assign multiple value to one key, just one of them will remain.

In your situation, the "apple" replaced with “False”

Answer (score 0):

I think it happened because `1` means `true` and you have overwritten the value of `1` (which was `'apple'` before) in the dictionary with `false`.

also, you can visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the) for more details.