# Why set in python not prints True, but prints False

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
myset = {3, 4, 5, 1, 23, 45, 23, 89, "rohit", "raman", "rohit", 4, 5 , True, False,  3j}
print(myset)

# Output-
{False, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3j, 'raman', 45, 23, 89, 'rohit'}
```

My question is why its not printing "True" in output, but its printing "False". If it can print False then why not True?

Comment: Because in Python `1 == True` and you already have `1` in the set.

Comment: Because `True == 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is False == 0 and True == 1 an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the)

Comment: @DallogFheir Oh i see, make sense tq

Comment: @MechanicPig Yes tq

Answer (score 0):

For `set` and `dict` types in Python, the rule for seeing if a value already exists is if any value in the existing `set` or `dict` compares equal to the new value, i.e. if `old_val == new_val` is `True`.  (It is assumed that such values will also have the same hash value.)

In this case, `1` and `True` compare as equal, i.e. `1 == True` is `True`.  When this happens, the old element is retained, including its type.  Since `1` appeared before `True`, the set ends up containing `1` rather than `True`.  If you reverse the order of the two elements, you'll end up with a set that contains `True` but not `1`.

You can see a similar effect with `0` and `False`.  Note that `0.0`, `0j`, etc. also compare equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a short look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set): *A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects*.

A set has to have unique members. And a set does not maintain an order.

Because of this, the doubled items 4, 5, "rohit" are kicked out. As `True==1` the `True` is also kicked. The rest of your items are rearranged, and as `False==0` it happens to be in first place, but with no guarantee that this will always be the case. If you add another element `0` with your set, preferably before `False`, the `False` will  also be replaced.

Remember, in Python your boolean variables are kind of integers.