# Unexpected behavior with expression in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem with this expression

x can take 0,1 and 2 as integer
y can take 1 and 2 as integer

```
a = [1,2]
x and y in a
```

if x is nonzero the expression returns True or False, but if x is 0 than the expression return 0. Why this happen?

The expression solved my problem, but I really don't understand why the expression returns 0 when x is 0

```
x in a and y in a
```

Comment: Assuming you are using Python 3.x, the integer 0 is also False: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the

Comment: I know, but why is returning 0 and not False or True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `x and y in a`, the interpreter converts it to `(x) and (y in a)` because of order of operations and precedence.

This is why you're seeing the behavior you do - `(x)` will implicitly convert whatever `x` is to a boolean. I'm assuming it's some numeric type, and any non-0 value becomes true, resulting in `(True) and (y in a)`, and any 0 value becomes false, leading to `(False) and (y in a)` (which is always false, because of boolean logic)

I'm not aware of any way to do what you wanted other than the conclusion you reached. Your solution, `x in a and y in a` is interpreted as `(x in a) and (y in a)`, which makes sense and is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should first understand how AND logical operator works:

- True and True == True
- False and True == False
- True and False == False
- False and False == False

Now for `x and y in a`, when x is 0, we can rewrite as `False and y in a`. Irrespective of the value of `y in a`, `False and y in a` will give False.

In Python 3.x, `False == 0` and `1 == True`.

You should also understand the order of evaluation which is not left to right for this case: `False and y in a` is same as `(False) and (y in a) == False`. Python does not evaluate `False and y in a` as `(False and y) in a` which is where your confusion is coming from.

For more details see:

- https://realpython.com/python-and-operator/

Comment: i know, but it's really strange because there is a "in" operation there. For example, if i use False in [False] returns True but if i use False and False in [False] it's return False, because the expession "in" isn't evaluated. Even if False and False == False and False is in [False]

Comment: I have added a note on the order of precedence. basically the `y` is bounded `(y in a)` instead of `(x and y) in a`

Comment: Even if the precedence were different, `and` does not distribute over `in` like multiplication distributes over addition. `a*(b + c) == a*b + a*c`, but `a and b in c` would not equal `a in c and b in c`; it would compute `a and b`, then check if the *result* were in `c`.

Comment: @chepner correct. I was looking for the term `order of evaluation` instead of `order of precedence`.