# Get Exception details on Airflow on_failure_callback context

Tags: airflow

Is there any way to get the exception details on the airflow `on_failure_callback`?

I've noticed it's not part of `context`. I'd like to create a generic exception handling mechanism which posts to Slack information about the errors, including details about the exception. I've now managed to trigger/execute the callback and post to Slack, but can't post the exception details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

An `on_failure_callback` can be supplied to the DAG and/or individual tasks.

In the first case (supplying to the DAG), there is no `'exception'` in the `context` (the argument Airflow calls your `on_failure_callback` with).

In the second case (supplying to a task), there is.

The contained object should be a python `Exception`.
It's surprisingly non-intuitive to get something like a stack trace from that, but from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35712784/2025495) I use the following to get a fairly readable stack trace:

```
import traceback

...

exception = context.get('exception')
formatted_exception = ''.join(
   traceback.format_exception(etype=type(exception), 
     value=exception, tb=exception.__traceback__
   )
).strip()
```

Comment: In my case `exception.__traceback__` is `None`.  I've also tried `traceback.print_exc()` and `traceback.print_last()`, but those also fail.  It seems that the traceback is lost by the time I get into the `on_failure_callback`.

Answer (score 5):

The error is added to the context [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/098b78d4b5c60e50e16fdd466fd5d4ca56a7b1db/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1058). So you can actually get that simply by doing:

```
context.get("exception")
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can get a stack trace or something like that from the context.

Comment: I just get `None`.

Comment: This only works if `on_failure_callback` is passed to a task, not to a DAG (as indicated in the answer by AdamAL)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably no way to get the exception detail inside the callback. [Look at the source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/__init__.py#L1590)

```py
# Handling callbacks pessimistically
try:
    if self.state == State.UP_FOR_RETRY and task.on_retry_callback:
        task.on_retry_callback(context)
    if self.state == State.FAILED and task.on_failure_callback:
        task.on_failure_callback(context)
except Exception as e3:
    logging.error("Failed at executing callback")
    logging.exception(e3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the traceback just do:

```py
import traceback

tb = traceback.format_exc()

print(tb)
```