# How to get airflow dag error information for fail status dags from airflow rest api?

Tags: rest, airflow

With /api/experimental/dags//dag_runs rest call, it retrieve status (success/fail). I need to fetch error if status is fail. is it possible to get it through any of airflow rest api call?

Comment: I don't think DAGs have any error; it is the tasks that have errors (stacktrace). Then i assume you want to fetch stacktraces of failed tasks. I can't find any such command in rest-api. I think the only way would be to configure [remote logging](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/write-logs.html) in Airflow and then use the corresponding logging system's API to fetch logs

Comment: Thanks for info. @y2k-shubham

Comment: by the way, you can retrieve exception message from `context` dictionary using `context.get('exception')`; check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57871605/3679900)