# How is exception passed to on_failure_callback?

Tags: airflow

I want to get the exception passed to on_failure_callback in order to check what is the error. For example, if it contains 'there are duplicates' in a certain DAG, the function won't do anything. Otherwise, it will send an email.

However, I am not able to see the format of the exception. I am using Airflow 2.1.2 in Docker and being my dag definition the following:

```
with DAG(process_name,
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='@daily',
         max_active_runs=1,
         tags=['import', 'es'],
         on_failure_callback=known_error_dag
         ) as dag:
    operators
```

The next solutions have been tried:

```
def known_error_dag(context):
    #  1
    ti = context['ti']
    ti.xcom_push(key='exception', value=context['exception'])

    #  2
    print(context['exception'])
    
    #  3
    logging.info(context['exception'])
```

I can see the exception neither in the UI nor docker logs. Also, it doesn't appear in XCOM.

The answers to this question make unclear if what I want is possible: [Get Exception details on Airflow on_failure_callback context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822029/get-exception-details-on-airflow-on-failure-callback-context)

However, Astronomer course states that it is possible indeed. https://academy.astronomer.io/astronomer-certification-apache-airflow-dag-authoring-preparation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `on_failure_callback` on the DAG and on the task level. Exceptions are only passed to the failure callback on the task level, so configure the callback either on your operator, or via `default_args` on the DAG to all operators:

```py
with DAG(
    process_name,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=['import', 'es'],
    default_args={
        "on_failure_callback": known_error_dag,
    },
) as dag:
```

The `on_failure_callback` defined on the DAG-level will also take context variables, which includes a key "`reason`", but that only states "task_failure" in case of a failed DAG run, so isn't very useful in most cases.

Comment: I have tried with this and still not working. If I enter into the Task Instance Details menu of the failed task, the section on_failure_callback has indeed my defined function, but I can't see any log/print and the xcom still not there