# Why does Airflow log Python exceptions at INFO log level?

Tags: python, airflow

In my airflow DAG, I have setup an `on_failure_callback` function that pushes exceptions to a Slack integration. I pass in the `context` of the task and extract the `exception` from the `context` using `context.get('exception') as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822029/get-exception-details-on-airflow-on-failure-callback-context) answer.

The problem is, it does not show the real cause of the Exception. The real cause is in the `INFO` section of the airflow logs while the `ERROR` section only contains the eventual errors that were caused by the real problem.

Example, below is a sample log that prints when I throw a custom error

```
2021-12-22 13:53:46,006] {pod_launcher.py:173} INFO - Event: transform-file-schema-6ba2b26845da43daa1b59ca5b221c839 had an event of type Pending
[2021-12-22 13:53:46,006] {pod_launcher.py:139} WARNING - Pod not yet started: transform-file-schema-6ba2b26845da43daa1b59ca5b221c839
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,017] {pod_launcher.py:173} INFO - Event: transform-file-schema-6ba2b26845da43daa1b59ca5b221c839 had an event of type Running
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,063] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'ERROR:root:Apatha throw error\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,064] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,064] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'  File "job_transform_file_schema.py", line 8, in <module>\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,064] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'    JobRunner().run(sys.argv[1:])\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,064] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/id_intl_dataflow/transform_file_schema.py", line 448, in run\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,065] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'    raise ApathaError("throw custom error")\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,065] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'id_intl_dataflow.transform_file_schema.ApathaError: throw custom error\n'
[2021-12-22 13:53:48,080] {pod_launcher.py:160} INFO - Container transform-file-schema-6ba2b26845da43daa1b59ca5b221c839 has state running
[2021-12-22 13:53:50,154] {pod_launcher.py:267} INFO - Running command... cat /airflow/xcom/return.jso

[2021-12-22 13:53:50,201] {pod_launcher.py:274} INFO - cat: can't open '/airflow/xcom/return.json': No such file or director

[2021-12-22 13:53:50,202] {pod_launcher.py:267} INFO - Running command... kill -s SIGINT 

[2021-12-22 13:54:16,091] {taskinstance.py:1152} ERROR - Pod Launching failed: Failed to extract xcom from pod: transform-file-schema-6ba2b26845da43daa1b59ca5b221c839
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 361, in execut
    final_state, _, result = self.create_new_pod_for_operator(labels, launcher
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 508, in create_new_pod_for_operato
    final_state, result = launcher.monitor_pod(pod=self.pod, get_logs=self.get_logs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 162, in monitor_po
    result = self._extract_xcom(pod
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 262, in _extract_xco
    raise AirflowException('Failed to extract xcom from pod: {}'.format(pod.metadata.name)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Failed to extract xcom from pod: transform-file-schema-6ba2b26845da43daa1b59ca5b221c83

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

As you can see the real reason of the error is in the `INFO` section:

```
[2021-12-22 13:53:47,063] {pod_launcher.py:156} INFO - b'ERROR:root:Apatha throw error\n'
```

Because of this issue, the `context.get('exception')` is not returning the true reason of a failure. What do I change so that `context.get('exception')` also has the INFO logs? Alternatively, what other variable in `context` can I use to get the INFO logs which have the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Are you using a different logger in your scripts ?

Comment: when I throw an exception, I am doing this for testing purposes:
        logging.error("Apatha throw error")
        raise ApathaError("throw custom error")
It still gets logged under INFO.

Comment: @Core_Dumped, Were you able to resolve or understand how to log exception?