# asterisk fastagi pyst2 python3

Tags: python-3.x, asterisk, fastagi

I'm making a fastagi app with python3 and pyst2 library. The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
######################################################

import asterisk, sys
import asterisk.agi
import asterisk.manager
import asterisk.config
import sys
import socketserver

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 4573

def custom_codes():
    agi.verbose("....... custom codes ..............")
    
class FastAGI(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            global agi
            agi = asterisk.agi.AGI(stdin=self.rfile, stdout=self.wfile, stderr=sys.stderr)
            global ddi_destino
            ddi_destino = agi.env['agi_extension']
            global ddi_origen
            ddi_origen = agi.env['agi_callerid']
            global agi_uniqueid
            agi_uniqueid = agi.env['agi_uniqueid']
            global agi_channel
            agi_channel = agi.env['agi_channel']
            global agi_type
            agi_type = agi.env['agi_type']
            handler = agi.env['agi_network_script']

            if handler == 'custom_codes':
                custom_codes()
            
        except TypeError as e:
            sys.stderr.write('Unable to connect to agi://{} {}\n'.format(self.client_address[0], str(e)))
        except socketserver.socket.timeout as e:
            sys.stderr.write('Timeout receiving data from {}\n'.format(self.client_address))
        except socketserver.socket.error as e:
            sys.stderr.write('Could not open the socket. Is someting else listening on this port?\n')
        except Exception as e:
            sys.stderr.write('An unknown error: {}\n'.format(str(e)))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    server_fastagi = socketserver.ForkingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), FastAGI)
    server_fastagi.serve_forever()
```

And, in asterisk, call with:

```
exten => _*X,1,NoOP(.......... custom codes ...........)
exten => _*X,n,Answer()
exten => _*X,n,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1/custom_codes)
exten => _*X,n,Hangup()
```

The app starts Ok, but, when I call the script, I view this error in console:

```
'agi_version': '18.18.0'}
    COMMAND: VERBOSE "....... custom codes .............." 1
Unable to connect to agi://127.0.0.1 a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Searching a solution with Mr. Google I view this post:

[TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003498/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

But i don't view any part to apply this.

any idea ?

Thanks

I don't view any part to apply the issue from python2 to python3 function

Comment: Your exception handling is weird. Remove that line with type exception or make correct trace for debug, you will line where is error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564559/get-exception-description-and-stack-trace-which-caused-an-exception-all-as-a-st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I've changed the code of original llibrary from :

```
def send_command(self, command, *args):
        """Send a command to Asterisk"""
        command = command.strip()
        command = '%s %s' % (command, ' '.join(map(str, args)))
        command = command.strip()
        if command[-1] != '\n':
            command += '\n'
        self.stderr.write('    COMMAND: %s' % command)
        self.stdout.write(command)
        self.stdout.flush()
```

To:

```
def send_command(self, command, *args):
        """Send a command to Asterisk"""
        command = command.strip()
        command = '%s %s' % (command, ' '.join(map(str, args)))
        command = command.strip()
        if command[-1] != '\n':
            command += '\n'
        self.stderr.write('    COMMAND: %s' % command)
        self.stdout.write(command.encode('utf8'))
        self.stdout.flush()
```