# How to log missing template variable, showing location and context in Django?

Tags: django, logging

I am following [this tutorial](https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/03/30/how-to-make-django-error-for-undefined-template-variables/) ("With a logging filter that raises exceptions") to catch all invalid variable names in Django templates.

myproject/mysite/logging.py:

```
import logging

class MissingVariableError(Exception):
  """
  A variable was missing from a template. Used as an alternative to
  django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist, because that exception has some
  meaning within the template engine.
  """

class MissingVariableErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
  """
  Take log messages from Django for missing template variables and turn them
  into exceptions.
  """

  ignored_prefixes = (
    "admin/",
  )

  def filter(self, record):
    if record.msg.startswith("Exception while resolving variable "):
      variable_name, template_name = record.args
      if not template_name.startswith(self.ignored_prefixes):
        raise MissingVariableError(
          f"{variable_name!r} missing in {template_name!r}"
        ) from None
    return False
```

myproject/settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "missing_variable_error": {
            "()": "www.logging.MissingVariableErrorFilter",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "WARNING",
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": 'INFO',
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.template": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "filters": ["missing_variable_error"],
        },
    },
}
```

When I load the main page I get this in the log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/install_dir/site/myproject/mysite/logging.py", line 27, in filter
     raise MissingVariableError(
www.logging.MissingVariableError: 'exception_notes' missing in 'unknown'
```

Problem 1: `exception_notes` does not appear in my site (see note below)

Problem 2: this stack trace is very large and noisy.

Also, the site serves an unfriendly error (this is actually what I do want, sometimes, in debug mode):

```
#> curl localhost
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

(This `exeception_notes` seems to be from `/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/templates/technical_500.html` or `/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/templates/technical_500.txt` rather than my own files, but that's not really the issue -- I can filter using `if 'site-packages/django' in record.pathname` although that's a bit hacky.)

I can get better results if I change `MissingVariableErrorFilter.filter` to simply

```
def filter (self, record):
    return True
```

which according to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects)

> Is the specified record to be logged? Returns zero for no, nonzero for yes. If deemed appropriate, the record may be modified in-place by this method.

sounds like what should be happening anyway, but doesn't. With this, the site loads as normal (with the missing template variables rendering as empty) but there is this in the log

```
www_1  | Exception while resolving variable 'form' in template 'index.html'.
www_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
www_1  |   File "/django-template-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 880, in _resolve_lookup
www_1  |     current = current[bit]
www_1  |   File "/django-template-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
www_1  |     raise KeyError(key)
www_1  | KeyError: 'form'
www_1  | 
www_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
www_1  | 
www_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
www_1  |   File "/django-template-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 886, in _resolve_lookup
www_1  |     if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(
www_1  | AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'form'
www_1  | 
www_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
www_1  | 
www_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
www_1  |   File "/django-template-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 896, in _resolve_lookup
www_1  |     current = current[int(bit)]
www_1  | ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'form'
www_1  | 
www_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
www_1  | 
www_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
www_1  |   File "/django-template-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
www_1  |     raise VariableDoesNotExist(
www_1  | django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [form] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: 'tuuBGDK1DEzWyNikznwXo85aK8gtQqtRE1knF43l2oZQsGk0CLBMvmewePqvEoBq'>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f2cd093e8f0>>, 'perms': PermWrapper(<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f2cd093e8f0>>), 'messages': <FallbackStorage: request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/'>>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}, 'debug': True}, {}, {'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/'>}, {'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f2cd093e8f0>>}]
```

Problem 3: this is better, but I only really need the first (`Exception while resolving variable 'form' in template 'index.html'.`) and last (`django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [form] in ...`) lines.

Having a `filter` that simply does `return True` sounds like it should be redundant, but if I remove `django.template` from `LOGGERS`

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "WARNING",
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": log_level,
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}
```

Then I get nothing in the log about the missing template variable at all.

How do I set up logging to:

- print the name and location of missing template variables (e.g. "foo on index.html line 123")
- also print the context given to the template
- optionally (e.g. in debug mode) raise an exception which makes the page load obviously fail

?

Answer (score 0):

Without wanting to do a lot of self-promotion, I tried to solve this as part of a package, [`django-robust` <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/hapytex/django-robust) I'm developing. The core logic is something that presents itself as a string, but will, when it performs string interpolation, log the error:

> ```
> import logging
> from typing import Optional
>
> from django.template.base import FilterExpression
>
> from django_robust.utils import get_request_from_stack, or_unknown, get_template_location_from_stack
>
> logger = logging.getLogger('templates')
>
> class InvalidVarException(str):
>     # prevent reporting the same exception multiple times, and thus eventually flood sentry for example
>     already = set()
>     # this does NOT work for variables with ignore_failures=True, like {% for ... in ... %}
>
>     def __mod__(self, missing, *args, **kwargs):
>         missing_str = or_unknown(str, missing)
>         request = or_unknown(get_request_from_stack)
>         path = request.path
>         full_path = request.get_full_path()
>         loc = or_unknown(get_template_location_from_stack)
>         key = (path, loc, missing_str)
>         show = key not in self.already
>         if show:
>             # prevent reporting the same problem again
>             self.already.add(key)
>             try:
>                 # wrap in try-except to prevent that exceptions trigger a 500
>                 message = f"Missing variable {{{{ {missing_str} }}}} at {loc} for path {full_path}"
>                 logger.error(message)
>             except:
>                 pass
>         # return the current string for rendering, we thus can still print debug information
>         return self
>
>     def __bool__(self):
>         # Trick the system in believing there is content
>         return True
>
>     def __contains__(self, search):
>         # Trick the system in believing the strings needs to be formatted
>         return "%s" in search or super().__contains__(search)
> ```

The tooling to determine the exact template file and path, etc. are also quite combersome, and therefore written in a [`utils` module](https://github.com/hapytex/django-robust/blob/0665021bcfd82b6fa05ddd18059f6d21b924c5cf/django_robust/utils.py) but can be extracted.

In the template settings, you can then set the `InvalidVarException` object as `string_if_invalid` option:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'string_if_invalid': InvalidVarException(),
            # …
        },
    },
]
```

of course you can set the logging to a different logger and handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought would be to raise the exception in order to catch it and extract just the first line which you want.

Here's an answer which illustrates the use of [`traceback.format_exc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564559/get-exception-description-and-stack-trace-which-caused-an-exception-all-as-a-st), deliberately raising an error and catching it to get the text of a traceback.

This is a minimize-coding answer. It's almost certainly horribly inefficient, but can that possibly matter?

Comment: The main problem is that this does not show the location in the template itself, since Django simply compiles the template into a node tree, so eventually it will have some sort of exception where this has been called by an `IncludeNode`, etc. but where that include node is located in the template is unknown.