how to run a chi-square goodness of fit test on fitting discrete probability distributions in Python
I am trying to test the fit of several probability distributions on my data and perform a Maximum Likelihood estimation and KS test on the fit of each probability distribution to my data. My code works for continuous probability distributions but not for discrete (because they do not have a .fit object. To fix the discrete distributions I am attempting to use a chi-square test but I cannot get it to work.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.stats import kstest

data = pd.read_csv(r'...\demo_data.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

#continuous variables
continuous_results = []

for cvar in ["cvar1", "cva2", "cvar3"]:
  #probability distributions
  cdistributions = [
      st.arcsine,
      st.alpha,
      st.beta,
      st.betaprime,
      st.bradford,
      st.burr,
      st.chi,
      st.chi2,
      st.cosine,
      st.dgamma,
      st.dweibull,
      st.expon,
      st.exponweib,
      st.exponpow,
      st.genlogistic,
      st.genpareto,
      st.genexpon,
      st.gengamma,
      st.genhyperbolic,
      st.geninvgauss,
      st.gennorm,
      st.f,
      st.gamma,
      st.invgamma,
      st.invgauss,
      st.invweibull,
      st.laplace,
      st.logistic,
      st.loggamma,
      st.loglaplace,
      st.loguniform,
      st.nakagami,
      st.norm,
      st.pareto,
      st.powernorm,
      st.powerlaw,
      st.rdist,
      st.semicircular,
      st.t,
      st.trapezoid,
      st.triang,
      st.tukeylambda,
      st.uniform,
      st.wald,
      st.weibull_max,
      st.weibull_min
  ]

  for distribution in cdistributions:
    try:
      #fit each probability distribution to each variable in the data
      pars = distribution.fit(data[cvar])
      mle = distribution.nnlf(pars, data[cvar])
      
      #perform ks test
      ks_result = kstest(data[cvar], distribution.cdf, args = pars)
      
      #create dictionary to store results for each variable/distribution
      result = {
        "variable": cvar,
        "distribution": distribution.name,
        "type": "continuous",
        "mle": mle,
        "ks_stat": ks_result.statistic,
        "ks_pvalue": ks_result.pvalue
      }
      continuous_results.append(result)
    except Exception as e:
      # assign 0 for error
      mle = 0

this code isn't running a chi-square test or ks test and I am unsure how to fix it:
#discrete variables
discrete_results = []

for var in ["dvar1", "dvar2"]:
  #probability distributions
  distributions = [
      st.bernoulli, 
      st.betabinom, 
      st.binom,
      st.boltzmann,
      st.poisson,
      st.geom,
      st.nbinom,
      st.hypergeom,
      st.zipf,
      st.zipfian,
      st.logser,
      st.randint,
      st.dlaplace
  ]

  for distribution in distributions:
    try:
      #fit each probability distribution to each variable in the data
      distfit = getattr(st, distribution.name)
      chisq_stat, pval = st.chisquare(data[var], f = distfit.pmf(range(len(data[var]))))
      
      #perform ks test
      ks_result = kstest(data[var], distribution.cdf, args = distfit.pmf(range(len(data[var]))))
      
      #create dictionary to store results for each variable/distribution
      result = {
        "variable": var,
        "distribution": distribution.name,
        "type": "continuous",
        "chisq": chisq_stat,
        "pvalue": pval,
        "ks_stat": ks_result.statistic,
        "ks_pvalue": ks_result.pvalue
      }
      discrete_results.append(result)
    except Exception as e:
      # assign 0 for error
      chisq_stat = 0

printing e:
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
_parse_args() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'n', 'a', and 'b'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'n' and 'p'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lambda_' and 'N'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mu'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'n' and 'p'
_parse_args() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'M', 'n', and 'N'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'n'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'low' and 'high'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
_parse_args() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'n', 'a', and 'b'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'n' and 'p'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lambda_' and 'N'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mu'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'n' and 'p'
_parse_args() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'M', 'n', and 'N'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'n'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
_parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'low' and 'high'
_parse_args() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'


Can you print the exception e you're getting and add that to your question?

I'm digging but https://stackoverflow.com/a/58764987/5369706 Using the traceback module might be helpful in debugging this as well.

It appears that the call to scipy.stats.chisquare takes f_obs (observed observations) and f_exp (expected observations), however, can be called with just f_obs "it is assumed that the expected frequencies are uniform and given by the mean of the observed frequencies."
