# e.printStackTrace equivalent in python

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace

I know that `print(e)` (where e is an Exception) prints the occurred exception
but, I was trying to find the python equivalent of Java's `e.printStackTrace()` that exactly traces the exception to what line it occurred and prints the entire trace of it.

Could anyone please tell me the equivalent of `e.printStackTrace()` in Python?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

```
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

When doing this inside an `except ...:` block it will automatically use the current exception. See http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html for more information.

Comment: If you're working inside some kind of container such as [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) and therefore cannot just print the trace, you can [`format_exc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) instead to get a string.

Answer (score 141):

There is also `logging.exception`.

```
import logging

...

try:
    g()
except Exception as ex:
    logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
    # will print this message followed by traceback
```

Output:

```
ERROR 2007-09-18 23:30:19,913 error 1294 Something awful happened!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 22, in f
    g()
  File "b.py", line 14, in g
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

(From http://blog.tplus1.com/index.php/2007/09/28/the-python-logging-module-is-much-better-than-print-statements/ via [How to print the full traceback without halting the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/print-the-full-traceback-in-python-without-halting-the-program))

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of this versus `traceback.print_exc()` ?

Comment: The biggest advantage is that you may control what/where you want to see by configuring your logger. You could, for example, use it to send the log to a logging service in production so that it is easier to fix difficult to reproduce problems.

Answer (score 25):

> **e.printStackTrace equivalent in python**

In Java, this does the following ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29)):

> ```
> public void printStackTrace()
> ```
>
> Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream...

This is used like this:

```
try
{ 
// code that may raise an error
}
catch (IOException e)
{
// exception handling
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Java, **the Standard Error stream is unbuffered so that output arrives immediately.**

### The same semantics in Python 2 are:

```
import traceback
import sys
try: # code that may raise an error
    pass 
except IOError as e: # exception handling
    # in Python 2, stderr is also unbuffered
    print >> sys.stderr, traceback.format_exc()
    # in Python 2, you can also from __future__ import print_function
    print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)
    # or as the top answer here demonstrates, use:
    traceback.print_exc()
    # which also uses stderr.
```

### Python 3

In Python 3, we can get the traceback directly from the exception object (which likely behaves better for threaded code).
Also, [stderr is line-buffered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr), but the print function gets 
a flush argument, so this would be immediately printed to stderr:

```
    print(traceback.format_exception(None, # <- type(e) by docs, but ignored 
                                     e, e.__traceback__),
          file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
```

**Conclusion:**

In Python 3, therefore, `traceback.print_exc()`, although it uses `sys.stderr` [by default](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/traceback.py), would buffer the output, and you may possibly lose it. So to get as equivalent semantics as possible, in Python 3, use `print` with `flush=True`.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to the other great answers, we can use the Python `logging` library's `debug()`, `info()`, `warning()`, `error()`, and `critical()` methods.  Quoting from the docs for [Python 3.7.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug),

> There are three keyword arguments in kwargs which are inspected: exc_info which, if it does not evaluate as false, causes exception information to be added to the logging message.

What this means is, you can use the Python `logging` library to output a `debug()`, or other type of message, and the `logging` library will include the stack trace in its output.  With this in mind, we can do the following:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def f():
    a = { 'foo': None }
    # the following line will raise KeyError
    b = a['bar']

def g():
    f()

try:
    g()
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(str(e), exc_info=True)
```

And it will output:

```
'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-8ae09e08766b>", line 18, in <module>
    g()
  File "<ipython-input-2-8ae09e08766b>", line 14, in g
    f()
  File "<ipython-input-2-8ae09e08766b>", line 10, in f
    b = a['bar']
KeyError: 'bar'
```

Comment: `logger.error(str(e), exc_info=True)` could be better expressed as `logger.exception()`