# Python IndexError after 2800 iterations

Tags: python, index-error

```py
    import config
    
    def parse():
        chat_log = open('chat.log', "r", encoding="utf-8")
        chat = chat_log.read().split("\n\n\n")
        chat_parsed = open("chat.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        lines = []
        try:
            for i in chat:
                if len(i) > 0:
                    x = i.split(" ")
                    if config.nickname != i.split(" ")[2] and config.nickname != i.split(" ")[4] \
                            and f"{config.nickname} = #{config.channel}" not in i.split("—")[1].split(":")[2]:
                        if "PING" not in i:
                            if len(i) > 0:
                                user = i.split("—")[1].split(":")[1].split("!")[0]
                                msg = i.split("—")[1].split(":")[2]
                                line = [user, msg]
                                lines.append(line)
    
            for i in lines:
                chat_parsed.write(str(i))
                chat_parsed.write('\n')
            chat_log.close()
            chat_parsed.close()
        except IndexError:
            chat_parsed.write('"[ERROR], [ERROR]"\n')
            chat_log.close()
            chat_parsed.close()
```

For some reason that I don't get, after calling this for the 2800th time (aprox), it gets into the except part. I'm using this to parse a chat log for easier processing later on a Twitch chat bot, so I have to call the parser a lot of times for it to be updated. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Also, the error seemingly comes from the `if config.nickname != i.split(" ")[2] and config.nickname != i.split(" ")[4] and f"{config.nickname} = #{config.channel}" not in i.split("—")[1].split(":")[2]` part.

Comment: By calling these split functions and immediatley accessing by index you are assuming a lot about the strings form. For example `i.split(" ")[4]` assumes that string `i` (which btw is named a bit misleading) has at least 4 spaces. It could easily be that it has less than 4 spaces, thus calling the fifth index `i.split(" ")[4]` would lead to an index error. To further debug this you would want to know more about the input data. I suggest you print out the string on which your code fails. Enclose the part `if config.nickname [...]` in another try-except-block, and `print(i)` on the exception.

Comment: Could you print what exactly is error? Also, in your code if you initialize `i`  outside for loop as `i = ''`, you can print the input as well when you receive the error. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555133/e-printstacktrace-equivalent-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, the problem here was the PING from the server, it had a different format than the other lines.

That was fixed by switching around the if instructions and first checking if PING was a part of the string. I had a new problem, though, the bot disconnected after a few minutes, just about the same time that took the last problem to be noticed. I was just not responding to the ping. Thanks a lot to the last answer, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a rogue input issue and not necessarily a code issue. probably a line in `chat` is not in a format you expect it to be. since `split` returns a list of varying length, you might not always get 5 members for each line, and since you access indexes 2 and 4 of the list, you would get an `IndexError` in that case.

For debugging purposes I would suggest putting the `if` statement in a try/except clause and print the line that is giving you an issue. then it's a matter of either cleaning up your data before running this script or handling lines like that in a way that you see fit.