# Print exception with stack trace to file

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, try-except

I'm trying to put a simple log into my script. This log should tell me where is the error and as much as possible info needed to repair the script.

I've put print to file `str(e)` into each except but it provides a very few info to know what is going wrong.

How could I make it elaborated? For example the whole not catched exception text which I can see in the console?

```
try:
    #code
except Exception as e:
   print_to_file(log.txt,str(e))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print the full traceback without halting the program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program)

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at the [built-in python logging modules](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial). This is a well covered topic; There should be no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 37):

try this,

```
import traceback
try:
    1/0 
except Exception as e:
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(e))
        f.write(traceback.format_exc())
```

If you want a better solution should use Logger that manage timestamps, file size, and rotation for syou (doing a logger handler)

this is an example with logger, timestamp and rotation

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import traceback

logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
handler = RotatingFileHandler("log.txt", maxBytes=10000, backupCount=5)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
try:
    1/0 
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(str(e))
    logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from python 3.11 You can also use [`TracebackException.print(*, file=None, chain=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.TracebackException.print) to print the exception information directly into the `file`.

> `TracebackException` objects are created from actual exceptions to
> ***capture data for later printing in a lightweight fashion***

```
import traceback

try:
    1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    with open("error.txt", "w") as f:
        traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(e).print(file=f)
```

This will produce the traceback like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/..../playground.py", line 4, in <module>
    1 / 0
    ~~^~~
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```