# logging.FileHandler doesn't write tracebacks

Tags: python, python-logging

I've 2 handlers to write to the console and the file:

```
import logging, sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="out.log")
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise ZeroDivisionError
```

When exceptions happen `StreamHandler` made for stdout is able to log the traceback which came to the stderr. Meanwhile, `FileHandler` doesn't write a traceback to the file.

Am I missing something in the FileHandler setup? Is FileHandler able to log `stderr` (e.g. uncaught exceptions) at all?

Comment: Are you looking for [print-exception-with-stack-trace-to-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636884/print-exception-with-stack-trace-to-file)?

Comment: No, as catching & logging err has 3 downsides: 1. you've to write some extra wrapping catching code. especially taking into account console handler which does everything for free as it doesn't require extra-code; 2. even if you wrap some entry point (e.g. `main` func) with try-except it doesn't guaranteed to have uncaught crashes logged when happen outside of it (e.g. import, syntax errors) 3. if exception gonna be re-raised the console handler is also affected by this change and duplicates the traceback twice which is weird (first from `logger.exception` and second from stderr)

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234491/2532408 might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Logging module doesn't do everything on it's own. You have to specify what to capture as shown below.

```py
import logging, sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="out.log")
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        logger.error(err)
```

Refer to these for more details:

- [logging doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging)
- [Logging geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/logging-in-python/)

Comment: I'm aware about possibility to catch exception and log it. And this was the first solution I came to and actually want to avoid as it is nice to write uncaught exceptions to the log file, isn't it?

Comment: btw, `logger.error` won't work too, only `logger.exception` is going to write traceback to file.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but, please see [logger-tt](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt), an awesome module that implements [this requirement](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt#4-exception-logging).