# "ConnectionResetError" What should I do?

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import re
import os

os.system("cls")

url=input("Url Link : ")

if(url[0:8]=="https://"):
    url=url[:4]+url[5:]

if(url[0:7]!="http://"):
    url="http://"+url
try :
    try :
        value=urllib.request.urlopen(url,timeout=60).read().decode('cp949')
    except UnicodeDecodeError :
        value=urllib.request.urlopen(url,timeout=60).read().decode('UTF8')
    par='<title>(.+?)</title>'

    result=re.findall(par,value) 
    print(result)

except ConnectionResetError as e:
    print(e)
```

TimeoutError is disappeared. But ConnectionResetError appear. What is this Error? Is it server problem? So it can't solve with me?

Comment: it would be nice if you could add the full traceback

Comment: the homepage is [here](http://jakjeon.icems.kr/main.do)

Comment: @VigneshKalai What is the traceback? how can i do?

Comment: see this so [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program) there they have expalined about traceback

Comment: It prints where the error has occurred and what the error was it will be easy to decode if we know that

Comment: @VigneshKalai The Error is in "result=re.findall(par,value)" The Error name is " NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Comment: That is because the value variable was not initialized that is the value variable did not get value in both try and expect both throwed error

Comment: we have to do debug step by step ok try just typing all imports and this line  `value=urllib.request.urlopen(```your url````,timeout=60).read().decode('cp949')` and don't take any user input

Comment: @VigneshKalai "SyntaxError: invalid syntxt" Error

Comment: @VigneshKalai [Picture](http://imgur.com/1NZAh3a)

Comment: url should be in `"` that is `"http:/www.google.com"`

Comment: @VigneshKalai I don't know this Error T.T [Picture](http://imgur.com/tSfFKO0)

Comment: did you `import traceback`

Comment: @VigneshKalai Oops! Sorry Here is [Picture](http://imgur.com/6QV59Qd)

Comment: remove result and all just add imports and run `value=urllib.request.urlopen(```your url````,timeout=60).read().decode('cp949')` what error are you getting

Comment: @VigneshKalai You means this? [Picture](http://imgur.com/u2xxqCz)

Comment: OMG don't give "google" give you school url and you are right

Comment: @VigneshKalai HaHa Sorry Sorry mistake [Picture](http://imgur.com/LNoHyHw)  The last sentence means "In this connection it was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: could you use other modules then urllib.requests

Comment: @VigneshKalai Nope T.T I can use only urllib.requests since I'm beginner

Comment: No idea of the error Googled it then to was not able to find it .All the best mate :D

Comment: @VigneshKalai I cant understand what you saying.sorry

Comment: There are people great then me you will eventually find the answer there is no need to be sorry I gained certain knowledge because of this question like wise you would have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

포기하지 마세요! Don't give up!

Some website require specific HTTP Header, in this case, `User-agent`. So you need to set this header in your request.

Change your request like this (17 - 20 line of your code)

```
# Make request object
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"User-agent": "Python urllib test"}) 

# Open url using request object
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request, timeout=60)

# read response
data = response.read()

# decode your value
try:
    value = data.decode('CP949')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    value = data.decode('UTF-8')
```

You can change `"Python urllib test"` to anything you want. Almost every servers use `User-agent` for statistical purposes.

Last, consider using appropritate whitespaces, blank lines, comments to make your code more readable. It will be good for you.

---

More reading:

- [HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) - to understand what is User-agent header.
- [21.6. urllib.request — Extensible library for opening URLs — Python 3.4.3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) - Always read documentation. Link to `urllib.request.Request` section.

Comment: Thank you This problem is complete. Are you Korean?

Comment: "python urllib test" is not affected ?

Comment: Yes. You can change it to any string which is not empty. Yes. I'm korean :)

Comment: 감사합니다 ㅎㅎ. 저 글은 본인이 영작하신건가요? ㄷㄷ 영어실력이 대단하시네요.

Comment: 한글로 질문해도 되나요? 어떻게 사이트의 헤더가 User-agent인지 알아내는 방법을 알고 싶습니다.

Comment: Connecting to http://jakjeon.icems.kr/main.do from browser is accepted, while urllib is not, so it means that site checks something in http request. From that point, You can check what is required. And, NO, YOU MUST USE ENGLISH.

Comment: Ok.. It only exist "User-agent" in headers?