# Properly Implement Shutil.Error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, directory

I'm learning Python 3 and trying to write a script that will copy a directory. I'm using `shutil.copytree`. From the Python documentation it says:

> If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.
>
> This exception collects exceptions that are raised during a multi-file
>   operation. For copytree(), the exception argument is a list of
>   3-tuples (srcname, dstname, exception).

In the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.Error) they do this:

```
 except Error as err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
```

Here is my script:

```
def copyDirectory(src, dest):

    errors = []

    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
     except Error as err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])

source="C:/Users/MrRobot/Desktop/Copy"      
destination="C:/Users/MrRobot/Desktop/Destination"

copyDirectory(source, destination)
moveDirectory(destination,"I:/")
```

**Questions:**

1. How do you properly catch an exception that might occur when using `shutil.copytree` (assuming my above script is incorrect)?
2. How then would you view the errors that occurred, would I loop through the `errors` array?

Answer (score 9):

You need to either include the module name when you catch the exception:

```
except shutil.Error as err:
```

Or import it explicitly:

```
from shutil import copytree, Error

# the rest of your code...

try:
    copytree(src, dest)
 except Error as err:
        errors.extend(err.args[0])
```

To view the traceback and exception information, you have a few options:

1. Don't catch the exception. Your script will be halted and all the error information will be printed.
2. If you want the script to continue, then you're really asking a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3702675/2615940). I would reference that question; the accepted answer is written very well.

And by the way, you should avoid calling it an array. This particular exception object has a [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and [arrays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) are an entirely different data structure.

Comment: quick question, how then do I view the errors, just loop through the errors array?

Comment: Could you show me, just for my own understanding, how to implement traceback feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OSError to handle it :

```
import shutil 

def removeDirectory(directory):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
    except OSError as err:
        print(err)

removeDirectory('PathOfDirectoryThatDoesntExist')
```

OUTPUT :

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   './PathOfDirectoryThatDoesntExist'