# Get traceback in python exception

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass exception to my main function with the traceback but its not working as expected.

```
import sys
import traceback

def test_function():
    return 0/0

def task1():
    try:
        a = 1
        test_function()
    except Exception as e:      
        print e
        traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]
        raise Exception(), 'Error message', traceback       

def main():
    try:
        task1()
    except Exception, e:
        print e

print 'start'
main()  
print 'end'
```

Here is my result:-

```
start
integer division or modulo by zero
instance exception may not have a separate value
end
```

Comment: you imported traceback  and then reassigned it in your except clause. You may find what you need in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the full traceback without halting the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program)

Answer (score 2):

traceback is the name of the module, try using it's methods, like `traceback.print_stack()` which will print out the stacktrace like how you see it when you don't catch the error.

see more in here: [traceback doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)

you can use `traceback.extract_stack()` to get a list of tuples of the stack