# Find out variable name of object that caused an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Let's consider the following code example which I will use to raise an AttributeError as an example.

```
def test(first, second):
    print("My age is " + first.age + " and my neighbour is " + second.age)
```

Say I have the following class.

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

If I call the function with

```
d = Dummy()
d.__setattr__("age", "25")
test(d, Dummy())
```

I will get an AttributeError because the second Dummy has no Attribute `age`. This is caused by `second.age`.

My question now is if there is a way that I can find out what the name of the variable is that causes the error. Looking at the source code it is obvious that it is `second`, but how can I find this out in an try except block?

Comment: Why does your `except` block have to know which object caused the error?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Do you want to view the traceback mid-runtime? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3702675/4180176

Comment: @Aran-Fey, what I am trying to do later is some form of type reconstruction, where I try to collect constraints (e.g. needed type has to have age attribute) for inputs by testing a function with multiple (potentially wrong) inputs. If I know the name of the variable that caused it, I can find out to which I can add the constraint.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon, viewing the traceback seemed like a start but all I can get out of it is something like ```AttributeError("'Dummy' object has no attribute 'name'",)```. But here Dummy is the Type of the variable, not its name.

Comment: In the specific case of AttributeError, could you not parse the exception and check attribute & classname vs your arguments?   Also, some exceptions include more information than just the message.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of that as well. But I opted for the solution in the accepted answer, because I want a place where I the information of multiple exception that might occur later as well and I figured a proxy object would be a good place to start. Nevertheless for the sake of this question I think parsing the exception message would have also worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution which should also work in case a class is not under my control. This solution only targets the `AttributeError` but should be extendable in case other Errors need to be caught.

We still have the same test function and the same Dummy class

```
def test(first, second):
    print("My name is " + first.age + " and I am here with " + second.age)

class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

We can use a Proxy object to wrap each value we pass to the test function. 
This proxy object records if it sees an `AttributeError` by setting the `_had_exception` flag.

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, object_a):
        self._object_a = object_a
        self._had_exception: bool = False

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "_had_exception":
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, '_object_a')
        try:
            return getattr(obj, name)
        except AttributeError as e:
            # Flag this object as a cause for an exception
            self._had_exception = True 
            raise e
```

And the call to the function looks as follows

```
d = Dummy()
d.__setattr__("age", "25")
p1 = Proxy(d)
p2 = Proxy(Dummy())
try:
    test(p1, p2)
except AttributeError as e:
    # Get the local variables from when the Error happened
    locals = e.__traceback__.tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals
    offender_names = []

    # Check if one of the local items is the same 
    # as one of our inputs that caused an Error
    for key, val in locals.items():
        if p1._had_exception:
            if p1 is val:
                offender_names.append(key)

        if p2._had_exception:
            if p2 is val:
                offender_names.append(key)

    print(offender_names) # ['second']
```

The end result is a list with all local variable names -- used in the called function -- which correspond to our wrapped inputs, that caused an exception.

Answer (score 2):

For debug purpose, note that the error message explains what happened.

```
obj = object()
print(obj.does_not_exist)
```

### Error message

```
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist'
```

It is thus clear which attribute raised the exception. You can also recover that information though the `sys.exc_info` function if you think you might need that information at runtime.

### Narrow down your `try-except`

If that does not satisfy you, be aware that the purpose of a `try-except` statement is to catch exceptions you *expect* to happen. Thus if two different exceptions might arise in the same block, you might as well split it into two `try-except` statements.

```
def test(first, second):
    try:
        first_age = first.age
    except AttributeError:
        # Do something if first doest not have attribute age

    try:
        second_age = second.age
    except AttributeError:
        # Do something if second does not have attribute age

    print("My age is " + first.age + " and my neighbour is " + second.age)
```

### Use `hasattr`

Another option might be to use `hasattr` to check if the attribute exist.

```
def test(first, second):
    if not hasattr(first, 'age'):
        # Do something

    if not hasattr(second, 'age'):
        # Do something else

    print("My age is " + first.age + " and my neighbour is " + second.age)
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I think this will work in case the test function is under my control. If, however, it is part of a class I cannot change, I won't get the variable name.

Comment: What do you mean by the variable name? In you test? In the original code?

Comment: In the test method I call ```second.age``` which causes the error. I want to find out that it was the variable with the name/identifier ```second``` which caused the error. Maybe this is just not possible, I don't know

Comment: Then use the second solution: put a try except block around this line specifically

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `test` definition to split up the accessing of the attributes:

```
def test(first, second):
    f_age = first.age
    s_age = second.age
    print(f"My age is {f_age} and my neighbour is {s_age}")
```

Then when you invoke `test`, you'll be able to trace it to the particular line.

Comment: Yes, this would work. However, I try to found a solution which works even if the function that causes the error is not under my control.