# How to print the stack trace of an exception object in Python?

Tags: python, exception

How to print the stack trace of an exception object in Python?

Note that the question is **NOT about printing stack trace of LAST** exception. Exception object may be saved at some distant point of time in the past.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's a bit inconvenient, but you can use [`traceback.print_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception). Given an exception `ex`:

```
traceback.print_exception(type(ex), ex, ex.__traceback__)
```

Example:

```
import traceback

try:
    1/0
except Exception as ex:
    traceback.print_exception(type(ex), ex, ex.__traceback__)

# output:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "untitled.py", line 4, in <module>
#     1/0
# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: It's a bit inconvenient why? looks okay to me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well, there really is no reason why it's necessary to pass *3* arguments to that function. If a function like `print_exception(ex)` existed, that would be much nicer.

Comment: Other useful function would be `print_exc()` which get info about exception(s) from `sys.info`

Comment: See also [`traceback.format_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)

Comment: IMHO, `exception.traceback()` is a more cleaner OOPs-like syntax.

Comment: `traceback` doesn't work in many cases. For example if python code is invoked from shared library. @Jean-FrançoisFabre answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

you can manually iterate through the `__traceback__` attribute to print lines & files:

```
def function():
    raise ValueError("flfkl")

try:
    function()
except Exception as e:
    traceback = e.__traceback__
    while traceback:
        print("{}: {}".format(traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename,traceback.tb_lineno))
        traceback = traceback.tb_next
```