# Printing an exception that works on Micropython/CircuitPython AND desktop python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

I am writing a library that is supposed to work on Micropython/CircuitPython as well as on "normal" Python (i.e, like a Raspberry Pi). I have not been able to find a way to format or print exceptions with a stack trace that works on both!

I have tried:

```py
...
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

... which runs on desktop (Python 3.8.10), but on CircuitPython I get an AttributeError.

And I've tried:

```py
...
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exception(e))
```

...which runs on CircuitPython, but on desktop I get: `TypeError: format_exception() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'value' and 'tb'`

And I've tried:

```py
...
except Exception:
    print(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

...which runs on my desktop, but on CircuitPython I get another attribute error.

I've also tried the `print` equivalents of the above `format` functions. I've also tried everything on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/catch-and-print-full-python-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the-prog) StackOverflow. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086976/how-to-get-a-complete-exception-stack-trace-in-python). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742612/how-to-print-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception-object-in-python). I would ideally like to do this without defining a utility function that switches between MicroPython and desktop code -- A simple one-liner seems appropriate for a task like this.

Comment: Can you upgrade your "desktop" python to 3.10+? If yes, your 2nd version is a correct answer: since 3.10 all that exc_type/exc_value/traceback hell is almost gone.

Comment: I can make it a requirement for the systems I'm running on... Or use venv. Thanks, I wouldn't gave guessed that *upgrading* the desktop version would help since usually CircuitPython's feature set is lagging...