# Which is better way to write out and err of python

Tags: python, linux, stdout, stderr

I am writing python in Linux. I want to write the python output and error into different files than output them on the console.

Say if I have this python file `example.py`:

```
print('console output')
print(1/0)
```

I tried different way.
 1. By executing the following command
`python example.py >output 2>log`
 2. Update the `example.py`

```
logf = open("./log", "w")
try:
    print('console output')
    print(1/0)
except Exception as e:
    logf.write(str(e))
```

and execute `python example.py >output`

The logs are different. 
1st method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

and for 2nd method:

```
division by zero
```

So I want to ask:

1. why two logs are different? And how to make the 2nd output same as 1st one.
2. Which is better way of write error into files? Or there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks for helping with my questions.

Comment: For your first question, it sounds like you're asking how to output a traceback instead of just the error message - does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the script the simple, original way:

```
# example.py
print('console output')
print(1/0)
```

Use easy trick in shell:

```
$ python example.py &> log.txt
```

If you wanted some other custom behaviour on unhandled exceptions, set a [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

Answer (score 0):

To combine both stdout and stderr into one file, which is also helpful when using more (or less) command

```
python example.py 2>&1 > output
python example.py 2>&1 | more
```

To make each go into separate files

```
python example.py 2> error > output
```

To ignore stederr

```
python example 2>/dev/null
```

Hope this helps.