# How can I fix "list index out of range" error in my scatter plot on Python?

Tags: python, scatter-plot

Can you take a look at my code and tell me the reason why I receive 'list index out of range' error?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
view_count = dodo_data['view_count']
like_count = dodo_data['like_count']
colors = ['r', 'k', 'b', 'g']

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('View Count')
ax.set_ylabel('Like Count', rotation=0, labelpad=55)

for i in range(len(view_count)):
    plt.plot(view_count[i], like_count[i], 'o', color=colors[i])
```

[image: My scatter plot is here]

Comment: Which line produces the error? Can you copy and paste the stack trace here?

Comment: Please share the values of view_count, like_count

Comment: @Cedced_Bro plt.plot(view_count[i], like_count[i], 'o', color=colors[i])

Comment: can u share list counts of each one ?

Comment: `for i in range(len(view_count))` - you assume that you have equal number of elements in view_count, like_count and colors. That seems not to be the case.

Comment: @BeyhanGül I do not know the exact values, but given the scatterplot above I can say that: 
view_count = [180000, 290000, 310000, 380000]
like_count = [4000, 15200, 14600, 16700]

Comment: Yes, @MrFuppes is right. You have more elements in view_count than in like_count.

Comment: @Rishabh How should I fix this?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya I do not know the exact values, but given the scatterplot above I can say that: view_count = [180000, 290000, 310000, 380000] like_count = [4000, 15200, 14600, 16700]

Comment: @Rishabh you dont know that. maybe view_count and like_count have the same length but color doesnt

Comment: Yes @luigigi , that can also be the case. 
Reyhan Please paste the traceback here, that would help debug this faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program

Comment: @luigigi View count and like count are 69-row-long. So their length is the same and much bigger than colors.

Comment: @Reyhan then you should know why get a "list is out of range" error. You can either use the same color for all points or you have to work on a better assignment of the colours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for i in range(len(view_count)):
    plt.plot(view_count[i], like_count[i], 'o', color=colors[i%4])
```

You'll get output like this:

```
1 6 r
2 7 k
3 8 b
4 9 g
5 10 r
6 2 k
7 3 b
8 4 g
9 5 r
34 4 k
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `colors[i]`. You have used `i` to iterate over the length of `view_count` column. Instead try using a separate iterator for indexing `colors` list which iterates over the `len` of `colors` list.

**I've tried with a sample data , which I'm posting below. Hope it helps!!**

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Data = {'view_count':  [1,2,3,4,5],
        'like_count': [6,7,8,9,10],
        }

dodo_data = DataFrame (Data, columns = ['view_count','like_count'])

print(dodo_data)
```

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
view_count = dodo_data['view_count']
like_count = dodo_data['like_count']
colors = ['r', 'k', 'b', 'g']

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('View Count')
ax.set_ylabel('Like Count', rotation=0, labelpad=55)

for i in range(len(view_count)):
    plt.plot(view_count[i], like_count[i], 'o', color=colors[random.sample(range(len(colors)),1)[0]])
```

[image]

Comment: This works but I do not want to have a random sample.

Comment: Then make sure the lengths of colors list and view_count is same or alternatively, you can use different iterator for accessing colors list.