# Python3: must be real number, not str - Even after float() conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

I am trying to write some data to a database but I get the **error**:

```
must be real number, not str
```

After a keyboard interrupt (strg + c)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_logger.py", line 61, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)                # Sleep for a second
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The function is:

```
Temperature = BME["Temperature"] #Temperature String from a MQTT Device
Temperature_float = float(Temperature)
print(Temperature_float)
db = initDatabase() #db is a initialised database
cursorObject = db.cursor()
try:
    sqlCommand   = """INSERT INTO tbl_data_jakob (temperature) VALUES (%f)"""
    cursorObject.execute(sqlCommand,Temperature_float)
    db.commit()
    print("Inserted (Hopefully)")
except Exception as e:
    db.rollback()
    print(e)
db.close()
```

The main Programm is:

```
ourClient = mqtt.Client("MQTT_Client")        # Create a MQTT client 

object
ourClient.connect("IP", 1883)    # Connect to the test MQTT broker
ourClient.subscribe("tele/Sensor")            # Subscribe to the topic 
db = initDatabase()
ourClient.on_message = messageFunction        # Attach the messageFunction to subscription
ourClient.loop_start()                # Start the MQTT client


# Main program loop
while(1):
    time.sleep(1)                # Sleep for a second
```

Comment: what is the full error

Comment: `float(Temperature_float)` ? OR maybe you should use `%s` instead of `%f` ? SQL converts it to string to send it to database - so there is no need to convert string to float.

Comment: What is the value of `Temperature`?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: "must be real number, not str" is the full exception. @bab

Comment: You need to remove the `try...except` part to get the full traceback

Comment: When i stop the program it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_logger.py", line 61, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)                # Sleep for a second
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: In order to get the full exception, take a look to this: [how to print the full traceback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-print-the-full-traceback-without-halting-the-program)

Comment: put error in question, not in comment. More people will see it .

Comment: When the try...except block is deleted the program just continuous and ignores the error. @rdas

Comment: The Value of temperature is 21.9 (Read from a MQTT Json message) @ScottHunter

Comment: Everything is in the initial post now @furas Thanks for the ideas for improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Orignial:

```
sqlCommand   = """INSERT INTO tbl_data_jakob (temperature) VALUES (%f)"""
```

%f is wrong, you need %s

NEW:

```
sqlCommand   = """INSERT INTO tbl_data_jakob (temperature) VALUES (%s)"""
```

Thanks for all the help.