# FastAPI uvicorn not logging errors

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, uvicorn

I am learning fastapi, and I am starting a uvicorn server on localhost. Whenever there is an error or an exception, I am not getting the traceback.
All I am getting is : `INFO:     127.0.0.1:56914 - "POST /create/user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error`

So, It is difficult to debug, I am trying out logging module of python

```
 import logging
 log = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")
 log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I have also tried starting uvicorn with debug parameter

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dev = 1
    print("printing")
    if dev == 1:
        uvicorn.run('main:app', host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info", reload=True, debug=True)
    if dev == 2:
        uvicorn.run('main:app', host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info", workers=2)
```

still the same problem persists. I am in development phase and I need the error traceback, please guide.

Comment: I'm on it... I am currently tracing it back to the "uvicorn.error" logger which logs to stderr by default, but I got the same problem, but it definitely originates from a logging config where uvicorn.error is changed.

Comment: did you find any proper solution?

Answer (score 14):

## Solution / Fix

Now, when you execute uvicorn by the in-Python command `uvicorn.run(app)`, this is your next move:

take the ucivorn default logging config and add the handler from your application to it:

```py
config = {}

# this is default (site-packages\uvicorn\main.py)
config['log_config'] = "{
   "version":1,
   "disable_existing_loggers":true,
   "formatters":{
      "default":{
         "()":"uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
         "fmt":"%(levelprefix)s %(message)s",
         "use_colors":"None"
      },
      "access":{
         "()":"uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
         "fmt":"%(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - \"%(request_line)s\" %(status_code)s"
      }
   },
   "handlers":{
      "default":{
         "formatter":"default",
         "class":"logging.StreamHandler",
         "stream":"ext://sys.stderr"
      },
      "access":{
         "formatter":"access",
         "class":"logging.StreamHandler",
         "stream":"ext://sys.stdout"
      }
   },
   "loggers":{
      "uvicorn":{
         "handlers":[
            "default"
         ],
         "level":"INFO"
      },
      "uvicorn.error":{
         "level":"INFO",
         "handlers":[
            "default"
         ],
         "propagate":true
      },
      "uvicorn.access":{
         "handlers":[
            "access"
         ],
         "level":"INFO",
         "propagate":false
      }
   }
}

# add your handler to it (in my case, I'm working with quart, but you can do this with Flask etc. as well, they're all the same)
config['log_config']['loggers']['quart'] = 
{
   "handlers":[
      "default"
   ],
   "level":"INFO"
}
```

this will keep the logger from quart/Flask/etc. enabled when uvicorn starts. Alternatively, you can set `disable_existing_loggers` to False. But this will keep all loggers enabled and then you will probable get more messages than you wish.

Finally, pass the config to uvicorn:

```
uvicorn.run(app, **config)
```

## Explanation

When uvicorn's logging config has set `disable_existing_loggers` to True, all other loggers will be disabled. This also means that the logger quart and Flask use (which prints the traceback) get disabled. You can either set the config to NOT disable other loggers, or re-add them to the config so uvicorn doesn't disable them in the first place.

Comment: where can i find all the formatters like `%(client_addr)s %(request_line)s %(status_code)s` for "uvicorn.error"? i couldn't find them on uvicorn docs.

Comment: Maybe they just copied it from Flask or Quart and you need to look there, I couldn't find documentation on it either and just used it :D

Answer (score 6):

For "500 Internal Server Error" occurring during a post request, if you invoke FastAPI in debug mode:

```
app = FastAPI(debug=True)
```

Retry the request with Chrome dev tools Network tab open.  When you see the failing request show up (note - my route url was '/rule' here):

[image: Failed_XMLHttpRequest]

Click on it, and you'll see the Traceback text in the Fetch/XHR / Response tab window.

[image: Traceback_in_Response_Window]

You can quickly verify it by inserting "assert False" in your post handler.

Comment: This is great, but I still want to see the same stuff in my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a more elegant way of doing this, but a simple-ish hack is to make a middleware which just prints exceptions;

```py
import traceback

...

async def catch_exceptions_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise e


app.middleware('http')(catch_exceptions_middleware)

# Then your normal endpoint code;
@app.get('/error-endpoint')
def endpoint():
    a = 1 / 0
    return {"result": a}
```

---

ref: [How to catch and print the full exception traceback without halting/exiting the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-catch-and-print-the-full-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the)

Comment: If this prints to the terminal then this would be a better way I agree.  Too bad there's not just some built in config setting to do it, seems like everyone would need this.

Comment: What if the `endpoint()` method includes try-except itself?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari That should not change anything. If you decide to raise it "out" again, then this method would catch it again. you can have nested try-excepts.

Comment: @MarkSeagoe I meant If the `end_point()` method would have try-except itself, your top method isn't called. So I think the best way is to put `traceback.print_exc()` inside of any exception in the methods.